# Why call git branch --unset-upstream to fixup?

Tags: git, git-branch, github-pages

I'm more of a novice when it comes to advanced operations in git. I maintain my [blog](http://jatinganhotra.com) using the blogging framework [Octopress](http://octopress.org/). Though Octopress is not under any development since 2011, it serves my purpose well and so I haven't thought of changing anything so far.

FYI, my blog is hosted on Github Pages.

Today, while working on a new post, `git status` showed the following message:

```
On branch source
Your branch is based on 'origin/master', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)
```

The same message repeated for all the subsequent commands such as `git add .`, `git commit -m 'message'` and `git push origin source`.

- What does the message mean?
- Is something broken?
- If yes, what?
- Do I need to fix it?

If possible, please point me to a pdf/web article where I can read up on this and understand it for future.

More details:

```
bash-3.2$ git branch -a
* source
  remotes/octopress/2.1
  remotes/octopress/HEAD -> octopress/master
  remotes/octopress/gh-pages
  remotes/octopress/linklog
  remotes/octopress/master
  remotes/octopress/refactor_with_tests
  remotes/octopress/rubygemcli
  remotes/octopress/site
  remotes/origin/source
```

Please let me know if more information is needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 254, accepted):

TL;DR version: remote-tracking branch `origin/master` used to exist, but does not now, so local branch `source` is tracking something that does not exist, which is suspicious at best—it means a different Git feature is unable to do anything for you—and Git is warning you about it.  You have been getting along just fine without having the "upstream tracking" feature work as intended, so it's up to you whether to change anything.

For another take on upstream settings, see [Why do I have to "git push --set-upstream origin <branch>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37770467/1256452)

---

This warning is a new thing in Git, appearing first in Git 1.8.5.  The release notes contain just one short bullet-item about it:

> - "git branch -v -v" (and "git status") did not distinguish among a
>     branch that is not based on any other branch, a branch that is in
>     sync with its upstream branch, and a branch that is configured with an
>     upstream branch that no longer exists.

To describe what it means, you first need to know about "remotes", "remote-tracking branches", and how Git handles "tracking an upstream".  (*Remote-tracking branches* is a terribly flawed term—I've started using *remote-tracking names* instead, which I think is a slight improvement.  Below, though, I'll use "remote-tracking branch" for consistency with Git documentation.)

Each "remote" is simply a name, like `origin` or `octopress` in this case.  Their purpose is to record things like the full URL of the places from which you `git fetch` or `git pull` updates.  When you use `git fetch remote,`<sup>1</sup> Git goes to that remote (using the saved URL) and brings over the appropriate set of updates.  It also *records* the updates, using "remote-tracking branches".

A "remote-tracking branch" (or remote-tracking name) is simply a recording of a branch name as-last-seen on some "remote".  Each remote is itself a Git repository, so it has branches.  The branches on remote "origin" are recorded in your local repository under `remotes/origin/`.  The text you showed says that there's a branch named `source` on `origin`, and branches named `2.1`, `linklog`, and so on on `octopress`.

(A "normal" or "local" branch, of course, is just a branch-name that you have created in your own repository.)

Last, you can set up a (local) branch to "track" a "remote-tracking branch".  Once local branch *`L`* is set to track remote-tracking branch *`R`*, Git will call *`R`* its "upstream" and tell you whether you're "ahead" and/or "behind" the upstream (in terms of commits).  It's normal (even recommend-able) for the local branch and remote-tracking branches to use the same name (except for the remote prefix part), like `source` and `origin/source`, but that's not actually necessary.

And in this case, that's not happening.  You have a local branch `source` tracking a remote-tracking branch `origin/master`.

You're not supposed to need to know the exact mechanics of *how* Git sets up a local branch to track a remote one, but they are relevant below, so I'll show how this works.  We start with your local branch name, `source`.  There are two configuration entries using this name, spelled `branch.source.remote` and `branch.source.merge`.  From the output you showed, it's clear that these are both set, so that you'd see the following if you ran the given commands:

```
$ git config --get branch.source.remote
origin
$ git config --get branch.source.merge
refs/heads/master
```

Putting these together,<sup>2</sup> this tells Git that your branch `source` tracks your "remote-tracking branch", `origin/master`.

But now look at the output of `git branch -a`, which shows all the local and remote-tracking branch names in your repository.  The remote-tracking names are listed under `remotes/` ... and *there is no `remotes/origin/master`*.  Presumably there was, at one time, but it's gone now.

Git is telling you that you can *remove* the tracking information with `--unset-upstream`.  This will clear out both `branch.source.origin` and `branch.source.merge`, and stop the warning.

It seems fairly likely that what you want, though, is to *switch* from tracking `origin/master`, to tracking something else: probably `origin/source`, but maybe one of the `octopress/` names.

You can do this with `git branch --set-upstream-to`,<sup>3</sup> e.g.:

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/source
```

(assuming you're still on branch "source", and that `origin/source` is the upstream you want—there is no way for me to tell which one, if any, you actually want, though).

(See also [How do you make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/520650/1256452))

I think the way you got here is that when you first did a `git clone`, the thing you cloned-from had a branch `master`.  You also had a branch `master`, which was set to track `origin/master` (this is a normal, standard setup for git).  This meant you had `branch.master.remote` and `branch.master.merge` set, to `origin` and `refs/heads/master`.  But then your `origin` remote changed its name from `master` to `source`.  To match, I believe you also changed your local name from `master` to `source`.  This changed the *names* of your settings, from `branch.master.remote` to `branch.source.remote` and from `branch.master.merge` to `branch.source.merge` ... but it left the old *values*, so `branch.source.merge` was now wrong.

It was at this point that the "upstream" linkage broke, but in Git versions older than 1.8.5, Git never noticed the broken setting.  Now that you have 1.8.5, it's pointing this out.

---

That covers most of the questions, but not the "do I need to fix it" one.  It's likely that you have been working around the broken-ness for years now, by doing `git pull remote branch` (e.g., `git pull origin source`).  If you keep doing that, it will keep working around the problem—so, no, you don't *need* to fix it.  If you like, you can use `--unset-upstream` to remove the upstream and stop the complaints, and not have local branch `source` marked as having *any* upstream at all.

The point of having an upstream is to make various operations more convenient.  For instance, `git fetch` followed by `git merge` will generally "do the right thing" if the upstream is set correctly, and `git status` after `git fetch` will tell you whether your repo matches the upstream one, for that branch.

If you want the convenience, re-set the upstream.

---

<sup>1</sup>`git pull` uses `git fetch`, and as of Git 1.8.4, this (finally!) also updates the "remote-tracking branch" information.  In older versions of Git, the updates did not get recorded in remote-tracking branches with `git pull`, only with `git fetch`.  Since your Git must be at least version 1.8.5 this is not an issue for you.

<sup>2</sup>Well, this plus a configuration line I'm deliberately ignoring that is found under `remote.origin.fetch`.  Git has to map the "merge" name to figure out that the full local name for the remote-branch is `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  The mapping almost always works just like this, though, so it's predictable that `master` goes to `origin/master`.

<sup>3</sup>Or, with `git config`.  If you just want to set the upstream to `origin/source` the only part that has to change is `branch.source.merge`, and `git config branch.source.merge refs/heads/source`
would do it.  But `--set-upstream-to` says *what* you want done, rather than making you go do it yourself manually, so that's a "better way".

Comment: +1 for  "If you like, you can use --unset-upstream to have the local branch **marked** as not having any upstream at all."

Comment: I like everything about this answer except that it doesn't resolve my issue. HEAD looks like: `<commit_id> (HEAD->master, m/master, origin/master, local-branch)`, and I'm pretty sure `m/master` is the bogus one b/c when all branches are listed it shows up as `remotes/m/master -> origin/local-branch`. The workaround still works, but it'd be nice to actually resolve.

Comment: @taranaki: `remotes/m/master` (as shown by `git branch -a`) indicates that this is a *remote-tracking name*. It is not a branch name and it therefore does not (cannot) have an upstream set. If it shows as `remotes/m/master -> origin/local-branch`, that means that this particular remote-tracking name is a *symbolic reference*. Someone made it with `git symbolic-ref`. You can delete that symbolic ref with `git branch -r -d m/master`.

Comment: @taranaki: The only symbolic refs that work 100% correctly in Git are the ones named `HEAD`, so it's rarely a good idea to create one. This has gotten a lot better over the years though. It used to be the case that if you had a symbolic ref and asked to delete it, Git would delete its target by mistake!

Answer (score 200):

torek's answer is probably perfect, but I just wanted for the record to mention another case which is different than the one described in the original question but the same error may appear (as it may help others with similar problem):

I have created an empty (new) repo using `git init --bare` on one of my servers. Then I have `git clone`d it to a local workspace on my PC.

After committing a single version on the local repo I got that error after calling `git status`.

Following torek's answer, I understand that what happened is that the first commit on local working directory repo created "master" branch. But on the remote repo (on the server) there was never anything, so there was not even a "master" (remotes/origin/master) branch.

After running `git push origin master` from local repo the remote repo finally had a master branch. This stopped the error from appearing.

So to conclude - one may get such an error for a fresh new remote repo with zero commits since it has no branch, including "master".

Comment: This is currently nr 1 result for this error message `On branch source
Your branch is based on 'origin/master', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)` and, while subjective, it is more likely to be caused by cloning an empty repository so great to have an alternative answer here.

Comment: I think that's why it is always a good idea to initialize your new repository with the file README.md, even if it is an empty file

Comment: This is what I was seeing when using Azure DevOps and starting development from a client using "Clone in VS Code". Nothing existed on the server yet, so `git push origin main` allowed an initial commit to server.

Comment: +1 not much info around about `git init --bare` - being a Git newbie myself I just found that `git push --tags` _did not_ make the master branch, while `git push origin master --tags` did - thank you

Answer (score 16):

This might solve your problem.

after doing changes you can commit it and then

```
git remote add origin https://(address of your repo) it can be https or ssh
then
git push -u origin master
```

hope it works for you.

thanks

Comment: This would indeed help - the reason is detailed in my answer (In short - this creates the missing master branch in the remote repo).

Answer (score 13):

For me, `.git/refs/origin/master` had got corrupt.

I did the following, which fixed the problem for me.

```
rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
git fetch
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually torek told you already how to use the tools much better than I would be able to do. However, in this case I think it is important to point out something peculiar if you follow the guidelines at http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/. Namely, you will have **multiple github repositories** in your setup. First of all the one with all the source code for your website in say the directory `$WEBSITE`, and then the one with only the static generated files residing in `$WEBSITE/_deploy`. The funny thing of the setup is that there is a `.gitignore` file in the `$WEBSITE` directory so that this setup actually works.

Enough introduction. In this case the error might also come from the repository in `_deploy`.

```
cd _deploy

git branch -a
* master
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/source
```

In `.git/config` you will normally need to find something like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:yourname/yourname.github.io.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

But in your case the branch master does not have a remote.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:yourname/yourname.github.io.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Which you can solve by:

```
cd _deploy
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
```

So, everything is as torek told you, but it might be important to point out that this very well might concern the `_deploy` directory rather than the root of your website.

PS: It might be worth to use a shell such as `zsh` with a `git` plugin to not be bitten by this thing in the future. It will immediately show that `_deploy` concerns a different repository.

Answer (score 0):

I had this question twice, and it was always caused by the corruption of the git cache file at my local branch. I fixed it by writing the missing commit hash into that file. I got the right commit hash from the server and ran the following command locally:

```sh
cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/feature/mybranch \
echo 1edf9668426de67ab764af138a98342787dc87fe \
>> .git/refs/remotes/origin/feature/mybranch
```

Answer (score -6):

Issue: Your branch is based on 'origin/master', but the upstream is gone.

Solution: git branch  --unset-upstream

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The question is not about how the error can be fixed, he wants to know why this error is raised and if he should do something about it. Please address this in your answer.