# Why do I have to "git push --set-upstream origin <branch>"?

Tags: git, branch

I created a local branch for testing Solaris and Sun Studio. I then pushed the branch upstream. After committing a change and attempting to push the changes:

```
$ git commit blake2.cpp -m "Add workaround for missing _mm_set_epi64x"
[solaris 7ad22ff] Add workaround for missing _mm_set_epi64x
 1 file changed, 5 insertions(+)
$ git push
fatal: The current branch solaris has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin solaris
```

Why do I have to do something special for this?

Is there any reasonable use case where someone would create `<branch>`, push the `<branch>` to remote, and then claim a commit on `<branch>` is not supposed to be for `<branch>`?

---

I followed this question and answer on Stack Overflow: [Push a new local branch to a remote Git repository and track it too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6232535/608639). I'm guessing it's another instance of an incomplete or wrong accepted answer. Or, it's another instance of Git taking a simple task and making it difficult.

---

Here's the view on a different machine. The branch clearly exists, so it was created and pushed:

```
$ git branch -a
  alignas
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/alignas
  remotes/origin/arm-neon
  remotes/origin/det-sig
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/solaris
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need to do \`--set-upstream\` all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089294/why-do-i-need-to-do-set-upstream-all-the-time)

Comment: Thanks @Alexi. Unfortunately, the cited dup does not explain the ridiculous use case that is being represented by default. (Those are not rhetorical questions. I'm genuinely interested in the reason for the UX design).

Comment: Note that this is configurable. If you do `git config --add push.default current`, then git push will automatically create the branch in the remote repo if necessary.

Comment: For those who want to stop seeing this message forever, avoid the other answers and comments and just run `git config --global push.default current`

Comment: With the newest version of Git 2.37.0, you can run just "git push" to push new branches. No more "--set-upstream origin". Enable with:

`git config --global --add --bool push.autoSetupRemote true`

Answer (score 574, accepted):

#### TL;DR: `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/solaris`

---

The answer to the question you asked—which I'll rephrase a bit as "do I have to set an upstream"—is: no, you don't *have* to set an upstream at all.

If you do not have upstream for the current branch, however, Git changes its behavior on `git push`, and on other commands as well.

The complete push story here is long and boring and goes back in history to before Git version 1.5.  To shorten it a whole lot, `git push` was implemented poorly.<sup>1</sup>  As of Git version 2.0, Git now has a configuration knob spelled `push.default` which now defaults to `simple`.  For several versions of Git before and after 2.0, every time you ran `git push`, Git would spew lots of noise trying to convince you to set `push.default` just to get `git push` to shut up.

You do not mention which version of Git you are running, nor whether you have configured `push.default`, so we must guess.  My guess is that you are using Git version 2-point-something, and that you have set `push.default` to `simple` to get it to shut up.  Precisely which version of Git you have, and what if anything you have `push.default` set to, *does* matter, due to that long and boring history, but in the end, the fact that you're getting yet another complaint from Git indicates that your Git *is* configured to avoid one of the mistakes from the past.

#### What is an upstream?

An *upstream* is simply another branch name, usually a remote-tracking branch, associated with a (regular, local) branch.

Every branch has the option of having one (1) upstream set.  That is, every branch either has an upstream, or does not have an upstream.  No branch can have more than one upstream.

The upstream *should*, but does not have to be, a valid branch (whether remote-tracking like `origin/B` or local like `master`).  That is, if the current branch *B* has upstream *U*, `git rev-parse U` *should* work.  If it does not work—if it complains that *U* does not exist—then most of Git acts as though the upstream is not set at all.  A few commands, like `git branch -vv`, will show the upstream setting but mark it as "gone".

#### What good is an upstream?

If your `push.default` is set to `simple` or `upstream`, the upstream setting will make `git push`, used with no additional arguments, just work.

That's it—that's all it does for `git push`.  But that's fairly significant, since `git push` is one of the places where a simple typo causes major headaches.

If your `push.default` is set to `nothing`, `matching`, or `current`, setting an upstream does nothing at all for `git push`.

(All of this assumes your Git version is at least 2.0.)

#### The upstream affects `git fetch`

If you run `git fetch` with no additional arguments, Git figures out *which* remote to fetch from by consulting the current branch's upstream.  If the upstream is a remote-tracking branch, Git fetches from that remote.  (If the upstream is not set or is a local branch, Git tries fetching `origin`.)

#### The upstream affects `git merge` and `git rebase` too

If you run `git merge` or `git rebase` with no additional arguments, Git uses the current branch's upstream.  So it shortens the use of these two commands.

#### The upstream affects `git pull`

You should never<sup>2</sup> use `git pull` anyway, but if you do, `git pull` uses the upstream setting to figure out which remote to fetch from, and then which branch to merge or rebase with.  That is, `git pull` does the same thing as `git fetch`—because it actually *runs* `git fetch`—and then does the same thing as `git merge` or `git rebase`, because it actually *runs* `git merge` or `git rebase`.

(You should usually just do these two steps manually, at least until you know Git well enough that when either step fails, which they will eventually, you recognize what went wrong and know what to do about it.)

#### The upstream affects `git status`

This may actually be the most important.  Once you have an upstream set, `git status` can report the difference between your current branch and its upstream, in terms of commits.

If, as is the normal case, you are on branch *`B`* with its upstream set to `origin/B`, and you run `git status`, you will immediately see whether you have commits you can push, and/or commits you can merge or rebase onto.

This is because `git status` runs:

- `git rev-list --count @{u}..HEAD`: how many commits do you have on *`B`* that are not on `origin/B`?
- `git rev-list --count HEAD..@{u}`: how many commits do you have on `origin/B` that are not on *`B`*?

Setting an upstream gives you all of these things.

#### How come `master` already has an upstream set?

When you first clone from some remote, using:

```
$ git clone git://some.host/path/to/repo.git
```

or similar, the last step Git does is, essentially, `git checkout master`.  This checks out your local branch `master`—only you don't *have* a local branch `master`.

On the other hand, you *do* have a remote-tracking branch named `origin/master`, because you just cloned it.

Git guesses that you must have meant: "make me a new local `master` that points to the same commit as remote-tracking `origin/master`, and, while you're at it, set the upstream for `master` to `origin/master`."

This happens for *every* branch you `git checkout` that you do not already have.  Git creates the branch *and* makes it "track" (have as an upstream) the corresponding remote-tracking branch.

#### But this doesn't work for *new* branches, i.e., branches with no remote-tracking branch *yet*.

If you create a *new* branch:

```
$ git checkout -b solaris
```

there is, as yet, no `origin/solaris`.  Your local `solaris` *cannot* track remote-tracking branch `origin/solaris` because it does not exist.

When you first push the new branch:

```
$ git push origin solaris
```

that *creates* `solaris` on `origin`, and hence also creates `origin/solaris` in your own Git repository.  But it's too late: you already have a local `solaris` that *has no upstream*.<sup>3</sup>

#### Shouldn't Git just set that, now, as the upstream automatically?

Probably.  See "implemented poorly" and footnote 1.  It's hard to change *now*: There are millions<sup>4</sup> of scripts that use Git and some may well depend on its current behavior.  Changing the behavior requires a new major release, nag-ware to force you to set some configuration field, and so on.  In short, Git is a victim of its own success: whatever mistakes it has in it, today, can only be fixed if the change is either mostly invisible, clearly-much-better, or done slowly over time.

The fact is, it doesn't today, *unless* you use `--set-upstream` or `-u` during the `git push`.  That's what the message is telling you.

You don't have to do it like that.  Well, as we noted above, you don't have to do it at all, but let's say you *want* an upstream.  You have already created branch `solaris` on `origin`, through an earlier push, and as your `git branch` output shows, you already *have* `origin/solaris` in your local repository.

You just don't have it set as the upstream for `solaris`.

To set it now, rather than during the first push, use `git branch --set-upstream-to`.  The `--set-upstream-to` sub-command takes the name of any existing branch, such as `origin/solaris`, and sets the current branch's upstream to that other branch.

That's it—that's all it does—but it has all those implications noted above.  It means you can just run `git fetch`, then look around, then run `git merge` or `git rebase` as appropriate, then make new commits and run `git push`, without a bunch of additional fussing-around.

---

<sup>1</sup>To be fair, it was not clear back then that the initial implementation was error-prone.  That only became clear when every new user made the same mistakes every time.  It's now "less poor", which is not to say "great".

<sup>2</sup>"Never" is a bit strong, but I find that Git newbies understand things a lot better when I separate out the steps, especially when I can show them what `git fetch` actually did, and they can then see what `git merge` or `git rebase` will do next.

<sup>3</sup>If you run your *first* `git push` as `git push -u origin solaris`—i.e., if you add the `-u` flag—Git will set `origin/solaris` as the upstream for your current branch if (and only if) the push succeeds.  So you should supply `-u` on the *first* push.  In fact, you can supply it on any later push, and it will set *or change* the upstream at that point.  But I think `git branch --set-upstream-to` is easier, if you forgot.

<sup>4</sup>Measured by the Austin Powers / Dr Evil method of simply saying "one MILLLL-YUN", anyway.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309 would have set the upstream right from the first push. +1

Comment: If the common case is to {create branch/push branch/use branch}, then shouldn't the result of [Push a new local branch to a remote Git repository and track it too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6232535/608639) be something that actually works? And if someone wants {create branch/push branch/don't use branch}, then shouldn't they have to do something special, like `--set-upstream /dev/null`? Why is the burden pushed onto the common case? I really don't understand some of these engineering and usability decisions.

Comment: @VonC: right, that's the point of `git push -u`, but it really seems like `git push -u` should be the default, or at least the default if there is no upstream *yet*, and there should be a `git push --no-set-upstream` when there isn't currently an upstream and you want to keep it that way (for whatever incomprehensible reason :-) ).

Comment: @torek maybe the reason is "set upstream by default... to what?" The same branch name might not be *always* what the user want. Plus, If I create 10 branch but want to push only one, and I am in the wrong one, a git push, instead of failing, would silently push and track that wrong branch too. So... case of POLA I suppose? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)

Comment: " You keep asking questions like this because, I think, you've written off Git as "really obnoxious"."  Please keep this kind of speculation to yourself.  I came across this question because I also keep asking myself these kinds of questions.  I'm not the world's best UX designer, but even I recognize that the default behavior in this particular scenario could be better.

Comment: How to `git push --set-upstream origin master ` by default for all repo ?

Comment: @Mithril: you can't (make `git push` default that way), and doing so may be a mistake: you don't necessarily *always* want to set the upstream. (I realize you said "by default" which is much more reasonable than "always" and perhaps *should* be the default!) But if you want a command that does `--set-upstream`  by default, you can make write your own alias or script that does it.

Comment: Note that this is configurable. If you do `git config --add push.default current`, then git push will automatically create the branch in the remote repo if necessary.

Comment: "When you first push the new branch:$ git push origin solaris" -- unclear why I would want to do this. I simply used "git push" and it ended up in the remote branch.

Comment: @FrankPuck If your Gt did not ask you to set an upstream, why did you read a question asking why Git asked you to set an upstream? :-) In any case, Git is (a) somewhat old, with many versions, only *some* of which ask you to set an upstream; and (b) very configurable, so that you can set it so that it does not ask you to set an upstream. If it is not asking you to set an upstream, you don't have to set an upstream.

Comment: @Gogowitsch it will, but it still won't automatically set it as the upstream.

Comment: I would do `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master` and get `hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.`Then `git fetch`. Another `git push`shows the upstream message again, so I would `git push -u` and finally be a happy upstream master.

Comment: @Timo: yes, that's the case when the *name* `origin/master` doesn't exist in your own Git repository yet because your Git hasn't yet called up their Git to get their branch names from them and found that their Git has a name `master`. In this case it's because they don't even *have* a `master` yet. Your `git push` *creates* their `master`, after which they have a `master`, so that you have an `origin/master`, so that your Git can set your `master`'s upstream to your `origin/master`.

Comment: _"this creates `solaris` on `origin`, and hence also creates `origin/solaris` in your own Git repository"_ -- unless you have messed with `git remote set-branches` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47726087/1026) to undo)

Comment: @Nickolay: right, it all goes through your own mapping (which you can mess with). I didn't want to get into these details, but I do think Git tends to give people too much rope here and they end up hanging themselves. (Or to put it another way, the underlying mechanism might be OK, but the way it gets exported for people to use is not good.)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Could you please explain why [pushing to create a new project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/working_with_projects.html#push-to-create-a-new-project) does not fully set up the upstream tracking information. That is, `git status` does not report differences to upstream branch, `git branch -vv` and `gitk` are unaware  about upstream branch, `git log @{u}` aborts with `fatal: upstream branch 'refs/heads/master' not stored as a remote-tracking branch`. Even if I later configure the remote using `git remote add origin <remote>`, this does not change. Thanks

Comment: Replying to my own comment after I found another extremely [detailed answer from @torek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60357692/git-difficulty-getting-existing-git-repository-to-track-new-bare-remote-reposit)  that explains this behavior. In short, `git push --set-upstream` only sets up **complete** upstream tracking information when used with a remote name (and not when used with an URL or path). 

Comment: @AndyRay: most people probably *shouldn't* use `current`. That's why it's not the default.

Comment: Is there a way to `--set-upstream-to` as part of `git checkout -b` when you create and switch to a new branch?

Comment: @Merlin-they-them-: in general, no. There are two stumbling blocks: (1) you can't really get Git to run something after `git checkout -b` (though you can get pretty close with a post-checkout hook, or with an alias that you run *instead of* `git checkout`; note that you'll want it to trigger for `git switch -c` as well). (2) `git branch --set-upstream-to`, which you'll want to use to set the upstream, literally can't *set* the upstream until the target upstream exists. Until your `git push` works, it *doesn't exist yet*. So there's nothing to set *to*.

Comment: @Merlin-they-them: if you do `git checkout -b new-branch origin/master` to create a new branch `new-branch` based on `origin/master`, then the upstream of `new-branch` will be `origin/master` (see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchautoSetupMerge). But if you want it to automatically set up the upstream to the not-yet-existing `origin/new-branch`, then no it's not possible at (local) branch creation time, but see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73111252 for how to set it up at push time.

Answer (score 157):

The difference between

```
git push origin <branch>
```

and

```
git push --set-upstream origin <branch>
```

is that they both push just fine to the remote repository, but it's when you pull that you notice the difference.

If you do:

```
git push origin <branch>
```

when pulling, you have to do:

```
git pull origin <branch>
```

But if you do:

```
git push --set-upstream origin <branch>
```

then, when pulling, you only have to do:

```
git pull
```

So adding in the `--set-upstream` allows for not having to specify which branch that you want to pull from every single time that you do `git pull`.

Comment: @FrankPuck this is Git, it professes to be usable for offline use, but without Google or SO it's impossible to use as soon as you leave the "trodden path". Briefly explained: `--set-upstream` in `git push` (as opposed to `git branch` with `--set-upstream-to`) is what `-b` is to `git checkout` (as opposed to `git branch` or nowadays `git switch -c`). This is insanity throughout and you shouldn't expect anything less. Of course with `git push set-upstream` you'll want to specify `remote branch` whereas with `git branch --set-upstream-to` you use `remote/branch` (also known as commreftreeish ).

Comment: @FrankPuck the difference between the two is that git was created to be a distributed version control system without a central source of truth like CVS and SVN. The proliferation of centralized repositories such as GitHub have turned git into a copy-of-a-centralized-vcs model. This is why the push behavior did not include a single upstream. You should be able to push a change to whichever repository needed it. A friend's, a central server, another machine you own, etc. It is a way to share changesets, not a way to centralize versions.

Answer (score 97):

You can configure git to do this automatically:

`git config --global push.default current`

This is what you want in 99% of the case anyway in my experience.

Comment: Thank you, I always forget this. I made a gist if anyone needs to fork to remember https://gist.github.com/jottenlips/f1ad4c53c287e263caea420d7f8f8e20

Comment: I have been using this option, but it just moves the problem down the line - when the remote branch is created this way, you can't use `git pull` - it will prompt you to use `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> your-branch`, without even an easy to copy example.

Comment: That can be a problem sure. But I find that 99% of the time I create a branch to push a PR and then it's merged, making it irrelevant.

Comment: This is truly what the OP was getting at.
The "reason" they have to --set-upstream-to can be described by a novel, or it can be described by "you didn't git config --global push.default current"
I prefer the latter

Answer (score 29):

With the Git 2.37.0 version, there is no need to use --set-upstream origin.
You can use git push directly after enabling push.autoSetupRemote using the following:

```
git config --global --add --bool push.autoSetupRemote true
```

Source: [James Ide's tweet](https://twitter.com/JI/status/1546948817462800384)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I was looking for! This makes `git pull` after `git push` just work if you have `push.default = current`, it just assumes the remote branch and local branch have the same name. This is so much better than having to write the remote branch each time (the default) or than any of the other solutions posted. Thanks!

Comment: ooooh I was **not** aware of this, many thanks! Should be ranked higher here! 

Answer (score 25):

A basically full command is like `git push <remote> <local_ref>:<remote_ref>`. If you run just `git push`, git does not know what to do exactly unless you have made some config that helps git to make a decision. In a git repo, we can setup multiple remotes. Also we can push a local ref to any remote ref. The full command is the most straightforward way to  make a push. If you want to type fewer words, you have to config first, like --set-upstream.

Answer (score 22):

The `-u` flag is specifying that you want to link your local branch to the **upstream** branch. This will also create an upstream branch if one does not exist. None of these answers cover how i do it (in complete form) so here it is:

```
git push -u origin <your-local-branch-name>
```

So if your **local** branch name is **coffee**

```
git push -u origin coffee
```

Comment: `-u` is just  a shortcut for `--set-upstream`. Despite the upvotes, It's not clear at all how this answer remotely answers the OP's question. In the realm of "how I do it" recipes, boxed's answer below is much more useful, as it avoids typing the boilerplate every time.

Answer (score 14):

My understanding is that `-u` or `--set-upstream` allows you to specify the upstream (remote) repository for the branch you're on, so that next time you run `git push`, you don't even have to specify the remote repository.

Push and set upstream (remote) repository as origin:

```
$ git push -u origin
```

Next time you push, you don't have to specify the remote repository:

```
$ git push
```

Answer (score 9):

tl;dr If you want to not think about this but also not modify your configs:

`git push --set-upstream origin $(git branch --show-current)`

Answer (score 0):

**In my scenario, the complication differed.**

Within the overarching `~/.ssh` directory, a pivotal file named `config` resides, which you can either locate or generate.

When managing multiple SSH keys and necessitating distinct ones for Git, the following code proves invaluable:

```
Host github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Essentially, this snippet facilitates the utilization of a custom SSH key. In my configuration, I originally specified `id_git` as the `IdentityFile`.

However, I later replaced it with the one specified in my GitHub account settings under `Account Settings > SSH keys`.

Subsequently, all functionalities resumed seamlessly.