# I need help changing GitHub accounts in Git on my computer

Tags: git, github

So I have multiple GitHub accounts and I really want to be able to change GitHub accounts in Git on my computer. Does anyone know how to do this?

When I try to push to my other account, I get this error:
remote: Permission to  denied to .
fatal: unable to access <'my repo'>: The requested URL returned error: 403

Thanks.

Comment: As [e.doroskevic said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38818090/1256452), you need—or your Git needs—to *authenticate* to the server. Authentication is a side issue for Git: Git leaves it to other programs. Exactly *which* programs, depends on whether you push with `https://` or `ssh://`, and also on whether you're on Windows, MacOS, or a Unix-like system. So you should probably specify your OS. (The "error 403" demonstrates that you're using `https://`.)

Comment: I'm running windows 10 on https://

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you do `git push [-u] <remote> <branch>`, git system will require you to *authanticate* by providing the *username* and *password* of your *Git Hub* account.

So, say I have cloned a remote repository from *account01*

```
git clone <url>
```

I do some work (*add, modify, delete* some files) and then I do

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
```

Now, when I push

```
git push -u <upstream_name> <branch>
```

*Note* : `-u` for upstream (I may be wrong!)

git will ask me to provide my account details in a form of *username* and *password*. After I have provided git with this information, the push instruction will commence.

**EDIT 1**

If you are trying to push to a remote repoistory located on *account01* from *account02*, you may need to configure **Collaborators** on a remote repository located at *account01*. Simply

1. Log in with your account
2. Click on the remote repository you want to allow collaboration on
3. Click on *Settings*
4. Click on *Collaborators*
5. Write your *account02* username
6. Click *Add collaborator*
7. Go to your email address which you used to create *account02*
8. Accept collaboration request

At this point you will be able push directly to this remote repository from *account02*

Comment: For some reason mine is saved and I don't get prompted to login. Is there a way to fix that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you push? Can you provide the instructions you pass on to git?

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thank you very much I appreciate it! That was super helpful and I'm glad this problem could be solved.

Comment: The `-u` flag on `git push` is shorthand for "set upstream": it means that *if the push succeeds*, Git should subsequently run `git branch --set-upstream-to` for you.  You can of course do this yourself instead, so `-u` is never technically required.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6089294/1256452 and/or http://stackoverflow.com/q/37770467/1256452

Answer (score 0):

Before pushing go to credential manager, than windows credential and delete personel access token of github and now you can push using different github account.