# Setting upstream for new branch

Tags: git, github, version-control

Alright ! I have created a branch `prac`. I am doing my changes, committing them and merging them with master.

In short this is what I do usually for my workflow consisting of two branches namely - Master and prac. Whenever, I want to do something, I code in prac branch

1. git checkout prac
2. git add whatever, git commit -m "so n so"
3. git checkout master
4. git merge prac

I do not delete my branch usually to be in a frame of mind that I always have one branch for practice and master for showcase of final code.Comments are welcome to improve my mindset :D

Now, I deliberately hit `git push`. I noticed the following

> fatal: The current branch prac has no upstream branch.
>   To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

```
git push --set-upstream origin prac
```

Now, my questions is that if I set upstream for this prac branch to remote, then will I need to do merge ? Or how basically it's different from merging?

From what I understand, after setting upstream, I already have pushed the changes to main repo. So what will be left to merge ? Or does this pushes to some new instance/fork which has to be pushed later ?

Confusion my friends confusion!!!

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37770744/1256452) to a related question, which describes what an upstream setting is, and what it does for you.

Comment: Thanks @torek. Lot to read and consume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `upstream` setting is a relationship between your local branch and a branch on the remote repo.  It has nothing to do with merging one local branch into another (except possibly if you contrive a perverse combination of config settings); it affects how refs are updated when doing a `push` (in situations where no configuration or command argument specifies a different behavior), and (as torek points out in comments) can also serve as a default ref for merging.

So now `git push` will, by default, update the `prac` branch on `origin` if you're on the `prac` branch locally.  But this doesn't incorporate your `prac` changes into `master` on either repo - which is what `merge` does.

Comment: This isn't quite right: the upstream setting affects how `git merge` behaves when run with no arguments (provided you haven't disabled this with `git config merge.defaultToUpstream false` anyway).

Comment: Huh... I didn't even know `merge` *had* default behavior for what to merge.  Shows how thoroughly I've read the docs, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

It struck me seeing a dropdown on another repo that it has branches listed. So I pushed my branch by setting upstream and it did what I thought. It simply added a new branch to my repo along with master.

So I guess this answers my query

> From what I understand, after setting upstream, I already have pushed
>   the changes to main repo. So what will be left to merge ? Or does this
>   pushes to some new instance/fork which has to be pushed later ?

Also from this I am clear about the merge thing as well. It's comparing apples and oranges.

However, useful article pointed by torek about merge and detailed insight. Now after doing this Mark's answer makes a  bit more sense. Therefore accepting that