# Undo set-branches on git remote

Tags: git, git-remote

I've currently set up my git remote to restrict which branches are fetched:

```
git remote set-branches myOrigin myBranch
```

This adds the proper entries to `.git/config`:

```
[remote "myOrigin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/myBranch:refs/remotes/myOrigin/myBranch
```

Now I want to undo this, and go back to the default configuration:

```
[remote "myOrigin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/myOrigin/*
```

How can I do this without manually modifying my `.git/config`? Is there a `git` command I can run?

Comment: Did you try `git remote set-branches myOrigin '*'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use quoted star:

```
git remote set-branches myOrigin '*'
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions:

```
git config remote.myOrigin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/myOrigin/*
```