# Git clone multiple specific branches

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I am trying to clone multiple specific branches in a repository.

I know it is possible to clone one specific branch using `--single-branch`, but what if I want 2 specific branches and no other branch?

I know I can use `git config remote.origin.fetch` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714159/how-do-i-undo-a-single-branch-clone) to change the regex of the "monitored" branches, but can I do this when I clone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this with `git clone` directly, but you don't need to.

Remember that `git clone` is short for doing `git init`, `git remote add`, `git fetch`, and `git checkout` (more precisely there are six steps but this is the gist).  The `git remote add` command itself can add multiple single branches, while `git clone` cannot.

Hence, the two ways to go are:

- split out the commands needed so that you can run `git remote add` yourself
- or, probably easier, do a single-branch clone, then `git remote set-branches origin` each of the remaining branches (one per command or all at once).

If you use the `git remote set-branches` method, remember to run `git fetch` again afterward.

Comment: For those like me that saw `git remote set-branches <remote> <branch>` and thought "hell yes I can use this for my one-off branch fetch": note that this will reset your refspec until you reset it. To go back to fetching all branches, you need to use `git remote set-branches <remote> '*'` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47726250/2752888)

Comment: @ZNK: right - for a one-off, it's better to run `git fetch <repository> <refspec>` with an explicit refspec. You can use a remote name, or a raw URL, for the `<repository>` part; if you use a URL, Git can't update any remote-tracking names (though a sort-of-bug in `git push -u` will sometimes appear to claim otherwise).

Comment: when i add some branches with `git remote set-branches --add origin branch1 branch2` then `git fetch origin` will still fetch all branches. currently im using `git fetch origin branch1 branch2` to fetch only some branches

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to clone multiple specific branches from a different repository, what you can do is, firstly, to change your current repository remote by `git remote remove`. And then replace it with the target repository where your two branches sit by: `git remote add origin <new-repository-name>`. Secondly, run `git fetch`, which will retrieve all branches and updates, and after that, run `git checkout <branch>` for each of the two branches, which will create a local copy of the branches. All that's left now is to get the previous `remote` back for your repository in the way described above. This worked for me!