# pygit2: How to "git remote set-branches origin remote_branch_name"

Tags: python, git, pygit2

Title says it all. I am using `pygit2` and trying to figure out how to achieve following that I can do using git cli:
`git remote set-branches origin remote_branch_name`

Answer (score 1):

If might be simpler to [set the configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47726159/6309) directly (since [pygit2 Remotes](https://www.pygit2.org/remotes.html) has no obvious way to set the fetch URL)
Using [`Config.set_multivar(name, regex, value)`](https://www.pygit2.org/config.html#pygit2.Config.set_multivar):

```
repo_obj = pygit2.Repository(repopath)
repo_obj.config.set_multivar(
        'remote.origin.fetch',
        '',
        '+refs/heads/remote_branch_name:refs/remotes/myOrigin/remote_branch_name'
    )
```