# Why does this example use `git push` without `-u`, while another example does?

Tags: git

*Version Control with Git*  says:

> Pushes that use a refspec with just a source ref (i.e., with no
>   destination ref) **create a new branch in the remote repository**:
>
> ```
> $ cd ~/public_html
> $ git checkout -b foo
> Switched to a new branch "foo"
> $ git push origin foo
> Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
> To /tmp/Depot/public_html
>  * [new branch]      foo -> foo
> ```

*Git Pocket Guide* says:

> If **you have added a local branch of your own and want to start sharing
>   it with others**, use the -u option to have Git add your branch to the
>   remote, and set up tracking for your local branch in the usual way,
>   for example:
>
> ```
> $ git push -u origin new-branch
> ```
>
> After this initial setup you can use just git push on this branch,
>   with no options or arguments, to push to the same remote.

What differences are between the things which they try to accomplish?

Why does the first not use `-u`, while the second does?

Answer (score 3):

If your question is about *what the `-u` option to `git push` does*, it's a duplicate: see [Why do I have to "git push --set-upstream origin <branch>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37770467/1256452) and [How do I push a new local branch to a remote Git repository and track it too?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2765421/1256452)  This answer is about why a book from 2012 does not include an option that wasn't particularly necessary back then.

---

Assuming you mean [this specific book, *Version Control with Git*, published in August 2012](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022862.do), the reason it does not suggest using `git push -u` is that it was published in 2012.

Git version 2.0 is dated:

```
$ git show v2.0.0
tag v2.0.0
Tagger: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Wed May 28 11:04:29 2014 -0700
```

which, as you can see, is rather later than 2012.  Now take a look at version 1.7.11:

```
$ git show v1.7.11
tag v1.7.11
Tagger: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Sun Jun 17 14:07:26 2012 -0700
```

While this is 2012, it's late enough in 2012 that it was probably too late for the book.

It's not clear to me what *Git Pocket Reference* refers to, but probably it was written, or updated, after Git 2.0 came out.

#### Why 2.0 and 1.7.11 are relevant

Git version 1.7.11 introduced a new setting for `push.default` named `simple`.  When using the `simple` setting, Git imposes a new requirement on defaulted `git push` operations: the *upstream* name of the branch you're pushing must match the *local* name.  That is, if the upstream of your `dev` is `origin/develop`, `git push` with no refspec will *fail*.  Meanwhile, if there is *no* upstream for your `dev`, `git push` with no refspec will also fail.

(When using the `push.default` setting named `matching`, both of these defaulted `git push` operations will run to completion, but will push your `dev` to `dev` on `origin` if it exists, or not push your `dev` at all if `origin` has no `dev`.)

**If you, personally, left `push.default` *unset*, the setting is treated as `matching` in Git versions that predate 2.0, and as `simple` in Git versions 2.0 and higher.  Since all or most of the book was written *before* Git 1.7.11 came out, it could hardly consider how the `simple` setting would affect `git push`.**  So it does not mention the `-u` option.

Modern descriptions will note that `--set-upstream` is important, so that future `git push` operations without refspecs will behave the way you would like, assuming you are using Git version 2.0 or later and have chosen a non-default `push.default`.  So they will call for `git push --set-upstream origin new-branch`, or the same with the shorter `-u` spelling (which means the same thing in `git push`).

Comment: Thanks. Does `git push -u` set up the remote branch as an upstream branch of the pushed local branch in `branch.<name>.merge`? `git push` also creates remote tracking branch for the upstream branch, and does it also set up its association between the upstream branch and the remote tracking branch in `remote.<name>.fetch`?

Comment: `git push -u <remote> <refspec>` first does the push as usual (which creates or updates the correct remote-tracking branch) and then acts like you ran `git branch --set-upstream-to`. So this means if the local branch you pushed had no upstream, now it has one, and if it had one before, now it has a new one (which may or may not match the one it had before). Consult the documentation for the `git branch --set-upstream-to` command to see precisely what that does.