# Can git fetch and git pull set up tracking relation?

Tags: git

`git push -u` can set up tracking relation between  an upstream branch and a local tracking branch, see [Why does this example use `git push` without `-u`, while another example does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54154493/why-does-this-example-use-git-push-without-u-while-another-example-does)

Can `git fetch` also set up tracking relation between an upstream branch and a remote tracking branch, as defined in `remote.<remote>.fetch`, possibly by some option?

Can `git pull`  set up either or both of the tracking relation between an upstream branch and a remote tracking branch, and the tracking relation between  an upstream branch and a local tracking branch, possibly by some option?

Comment: I don't think fetch works on a per branch basis.

Answer (score 1):

No, apparently it cannot: the obvious `git fetch origin <branch_name>:<branch_name>`, which fetches `origin/<branch_name>` and updates `<branch_name>` to point to it, does not create the tracking relationship if it does not already exist.

This is how I usually create the tracking relationship:

```
git fetch origin <branch_name>
git checkout <branch_name>
```

If the local branch does not already exist when you do the checkout, it will be created as a tracking branch.

This command creates the branch without checking it out:

```
git branch -u <branch_name> origin/<branch_name>
```