# How to use git branch patterns?

Tags: git

When performing a git checkout on, for example, the Linux kernel tree to get a specific branch, I am using a pattern:

```
git checkout rpi-4.19.y
```

This branch corresponds to a kernel tree for Raspberry Pi and as far as I can tell, causes git to pull the latest named iteration of this branch, which at the current time would be 4.19.63-v7+.

So that 'y' in the command pattern matches to '63-v7+'. I can't find what this behavior is called, so it's very hard to search for. I am trying to find out what other named branches would be available, before actually checking out in this way. I.e., I'm scripting this and want to capture this detail before checkout occurs.

Comment: You are checking out **branch**, while talking about **tag** (*named iteration* in your words).

Comment: Is there a way to tell if this is a branch or a tag and do they both have this similar trait that you can ask for them by pattern?

Comment: I think your best bet would be to look at `git ls-remote` and take a look at what comes back, anything starting with `refs/heads/` is a branch.

Answer (score 1):

First: be careful with the word *pull* when talking about Git, because `git pull` is a Git command that means: *run `git fetch`, then if that succeeds, run a second Git command, usually `git merge`*.  To "pull" a branch therefore means to run `git fetch` and then run `git merge` with a commit based on the result.  Well, that is, unless you've configured or instructed `git pull` to use a *different* second command, in which case, it means something different—but it still starts with `git fetch`.

(In scripts, you should often *avoid* `git pull`, because the way it behaves depends on the user's configuration.  You have to decide whether you want to change what your script does based on the user's configuration.)

All that said, what `git checkout` does is ... a little bit complicated.  While it sometimes does do a simple kind of pattern matching, it *does not* invoke `git fetch`.  That means you shouldn't think of it as pulling anything.

To simplify things, let's talk only about the command `git checkout X`, for some *`X`*.  (There are about four or five other kinds of `git checkout`, depending on how you count.)  For this one particular kind of `git checkout`, Git goes through a four-step process to figure out what you want, and then do that:

1. Is *`X`* an existing (local) branch name?  That is, if you ran `git branch`, would it list *`X`* as a branch?  If so, `git checkout X` means to check out that (existing) branch.  Afterwards, `git status` will say `on branch X`.
2. If *`X`* is not an existing branch name, can *`X`* be resolved to a Git commit hash ID?  To answer this question for yourself, you can run `git rev-parse X^{commit}`.<sup>1</sup>  If this works, `git checkout` will check out that commit as a *detached HEAD*.  Afterwards, `git status` will say `HEAD detached at X`, or in very old version of Git, `HEAD detached at hash` for some hash.

   The checkout itself will begin by printing, e.g.:

   ```
   $ git checkout v2.18.1
   Checking out files: 100% (1517/1517), done.
   Note: checking out 'v2.18.1'.

   You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, ...
   ```

   (though some of this changes depending on your internationalization locale setting, e.g., the messages might be in French).

   The example above could be what you're getting; it's what I got when using `git checkout v2.18.1` to name a *tag* in the Git repository for Git.
3. If both 1 and 2 fail, `git checkout` goes on to try what Git calls *DWIM mode*.  It now lists all the *remote-tracking names*, which you can see for yourself using `git branch -r`:

   ```
   $ git branch -r
     origin/HEAD -> origin/master
     origin/maint
     origin/master
     origin/next
     origin/pu
     origin/todo
   ```

   This is also a case you might be getting.  Note that each of these names has a pattern: each one starts with `origin/`, which is the name of the remote in this particular Git repository for Git:

   ```
   $ git remote
   origin
   ```

   This particular repository has only one remote.  You can have more than one remote, using `git remote add` to add more.  In that case, you'll often have multiple different remote-tracking names.  For instance, if I were to add remotes named `alice` and `bob`, I might end up with remote-tracking names `alice/master`, `alice/dev`, `bob/master`, and `bob/feature-1234` (in addition to my usual `origin/*` ones).

   For case 3, Git will take the name you gave it and look through *all* your remote-tracking names.  For each one, Git will take off the remote's name and the slash—for instance, `origin/master` becomes just `master`, `alice/master` becomes just `master`, and `bob/master` becomes just `master`.  The same goes for `alice/dev` and `bob/feature-1234`.  If *exactly one* of these stripped-down names match the argument you used, Git selects this "DWIM mode" checkout option.

   Note that if two or more names match—e.g., if I have both an `origin/dev` and an `alice/dev` and I type `git checkout dev` (and we're in case 3 in the first place)—then "DWIM mode" fails and we move on to case 4.   I'll describe "DWIM mode" the rest of the way in a moment; for now, let's move on to case 4.
4. Having failed at all three of the earlier cases, `git checkout` now tries to use *`X`* as a *path name*.  If that works, it does the equivalent of `git checkout -- X`.  This extracts the copy of file *`X`* from the index and uses that to overwrite the copy of *`X`* in the work-tree.

If all four cases fail, `git checkout` itself fails.  Note that if cases 1, 2, or 3 succeed at resolving the name *`X`*, but the *rest* of the operation fails for some reason, `git checkout` does not try any of the later cases.  The four steps above are done only to figure out what *`X`* should *mean* in order to decide whether to do a commit checkout (cases 1 and 2), a name-creating checkout (case 3), or a file checkout (case 4).

#### Branch-creating checkouts, including DWIM mode

The `git checkout` command has the ability to *create* a branch.  The most basic way to create a branch in Git is to use `git branch`.  Here, you pick some existing commit—often the tip commit of some existing branch—and tell `git branch` to make a *new* name that identifies *the same commit* as the existing name:

```
git branch new-branch a123456
```

(where `a123456` is the commit hash you want), or:

```
git branch new-branch master
```

(where you let the name `master` resolve to the commit hash, then create the new name `new-branch`, pointing to that same commit).  If the name `master` currently resolves to the hash ID `a123456`, these two commands accomplish the exact same thing, which we can draw as:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- master, new-branch
```

Now all the commits that end at `a123456` are on *both* branches.

Having made a new branch, you can then `git checkout` that branch:

```
git checkout new-branch
```

That puts you on `new-branch` while checking out commit `a123456` (again, assuming `master` meant `a123456`—use `git rev-parse master` to see the actual hash ID).

To make this all a bit easier, `git checkout` offers you the ability to:

1. create a branch name, and then
2. switch to it (and its commit)

as a single command.  Typically, to do this, you do the same thing you do with `git branch`: you pick out a *commit*, maybe using an existing branch name to do that, then you say: *Make a new name, make it identify that commit, and check it out.*  So you could write:

```
git checkout -b new-branch a123456
```

to do the same thing we did with `git branch` followed by `git checkout`.  That's not a huge savings, but it's convenient.  It's especially convenient when you want to create the new branch *from* the same commit as whatever branch you're on right now, because then you can just run:

```
git checkout -b new-branch
```

and the new branch's commit is the same as the current commit.

But there's more to set for a branch.  In particular, any branch can have one *upstream*.  The upstream of a branch helps you out a bit (or helps Git help you out a bit) when you run `git status`, `git push`, and various other Git commands.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37770744/1256452) for more—but in short, you might want to run:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/dev dev
```

after creating your own `dev` from the commit identified by the name `origin/dev`.  If you did this the hard way, it would be:

```
git branch dev origin/dev
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/dev dev
git checkout dev
```

or:

```
git branch dev origin/dev
git checkout dev
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/dev
```

(you get to leave out *one* copy of the name `dev` here as `git branch` assumes you mean to operate on the *current* branch, which you set with the `git checkout` command).

If you use `git checkout dev` *when you don't have a `dev`*, and invoke `git checkout`'s DWIM mode, Git assumes that you meant to do *all three* of these operations.  So a simple:

```
git checkout dev
```

does all three, and that's a pretty significant savings: you don't have to type `origin/dev` *at all*, because Git figured that out on its own, and you only have to type `dev` once.

---

<sup>1</sup>There a few exceptions for particularly complicated strings.  For instance, if we set X to the literal string`HEAD:/fix` and try to use `git rev-parse X:/fix^{commit}`, we'll get the wrong answer.  To get the right answer in all cases requires two steps:

```
hash=$(git rev-parse $X) || ... handle error; do not proceed ...
hash=$(git rev-parse $hash^{commit}) || ... handle error ...
```

If these two steps both succeed, `$hash` contains the hash ID of the commit that `git checkout` would check out.

Answer (score 0):

So it depends on the remote resource.  With that command it could either be checking out a branch or checking out a release.

A tag is a pointer to a specific commit. This pointer can be super charged with some additional information (identity of the creator of the tag, a description, a GPG signature, ...).

A tag is a git concept whereas a Release is GitHub higher level concept.

As stated in the official announcement post from the GitHub blog: "Releases are first-class objects with changelogs and binary assets that present a full project history beyond Git artifacts."

A Release is created from an existing tag and exposes release notes and links to download the software or source code from GitHub.

Comment: Is a release the same as a tag?