# Not seeing coworkers git changes when pulling same branch?

Tags: git

I created a branch (*new-branch*) based off another branch (*origin/Development*). I did some work and pushed up my branch to the remote. My coworker pulled down *new-branch*, made some changes, and then pushed those changes to the remote. So we are working on the same branch and my code is missing his changes locally.

Locally when I run *git pull*, it does not retrieve coworkers changes. I think because my local branch is still tracking *origin/Development*? How do I stay on my branch locally and retrieve his changes?

Comment: Did you try "git pull origin new-branch"?

Comment: any chance your coworker forgot to push his committed changes?

Comment: maybe this is because your local branch is not connected to the remote branch; try to do `git remote update; git remote pull;` if it turned to be the case then, everytime you should make sure that your local branch and remote branch are connected and do `git push origin -u LOCAL_BRANCH_NAME`

Comment: Ok I will posst it as an answer then :)

Answer (score 2):

Please try `git pull origin new-branch`

Answer (score 1):

First, check on your machine if your local branch `new-branch` matches the remote branch `origin/new-branch` :

```
# this will show the head commit of your local branch :
git log -1 new-branch

# does this command display something at all ?
# does it match the content your coworker pushed ?
git log -1 origin/new-branch
```

- If the second command did not display the work of your coworker :
  something wasn't committed or pushed from your coworker's station, check his copy of the repo.
- If the second command did display your coworker's work :
  it is just a matter of linking your local branch to the remote branch.

  Run :

  ```
  git branch -u origin/new-branch new-branch
  # and then :
  git pull
  ```

Answer (score 0):

> I think because my local branch is still tracking origin/Development?

Are you currently on `origin/Development` or `new-branch`.

If on `origin/Development` checkout on new branch.

- `git checkout new-branch`
- `git pull origin new-branch`

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

You probably want to set the *upstream* of your branch.  There are lots of ways to do this, but the most direct, at this stage, is to use:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/new-branch new-branch
```

after which all the shortcut stuff you're using will work.

## Long: what all this shortcut stuff *is*

To really understand this, you need to know:

- what a Git branch name really is and does (which is not much, but what it does matters a lot to humans);
- what a *remote-tracking name* is;
- what the *upstream* of a branch is; and
- how `git pull` works.

#### Branch names and remote-tracking names

First, regarding branches, there are several things to keep in mind here:

- Git isn't really about *branches* at all.  It's really about *commits*.  Commits aren't really named by branch.  They're really named by hash ID.  Every Git everywhere agrees that any one particular commit has *that* hash ID, and no other commit ever gets to use *that* hash ID.  But hash IDs look random, and are impossible for humans to remember, so...
- Branch names mainly serve to *find* commits.  That means that we humans depend pretty heavily on the names.  Each branch name holds *exactly one hash ID*.  By definition, that hash ID is the hash ID of the *last* commit in the branch.
- Your own Git has *its own* branch names, which are independent of anyone else's branch names.  But because these names are useful to us, your Git will also create *remote-tracking names* like `origin/master`, to remember what your Git saw in the other Git (over on `origin`), in *their* `master`.  Your Git will update these remote-tracking names whenever your Git gets a chance.

For instance, consider running `git fetch origin`.  This makes your Git call up their Git, using the short name `origin` to look up the URL (their Git's "phone number").  Their Git will list out some or all of their branch names, along with the commit hash IDs that go with those names.  Your Git will get these commits, if you don't have them yet, and any other commits that go with those commits, if you don't have them yet.  So now you have all of their commits—or all of the ones you need for the specific branch(es) you're fetching, if you limited your `git fetch`—*and* your Git knows which commit their Git's branch name identifies.  Hence, your Git now updates your *remote-tracking names*—your `origin/master` and so forth—so that you can remember their commits.

Remember, too, that every commit, named by its unique hash ID, *also* have *inside themselves* some hash IDs.  Most commits hold one hash ID: that's this commit's *parent* commit.  These parent IDs form commits into backwards-pointing chains.  That's why it's OK to just remember the *last* hash ID.  Given a branch name like `master`, Git finds the *last* commit in the chain, i.e., the *tip* of the branch.  That commit remembers the next earlier commit.  The next earlier commit remembers another even-earlier commit—the grandparent of the tip commit—and the grandparent remembers another even-earlier commit, and so on.

#### `git pull`

All `git pull` does is run two Git commands for you:

- First, it runs `git fetch`.  This is what actually obtains new commits.  The fetch step will also update your remote-tracking names as appropriate.

  The new commits you've picked up, if any, have not affected *any* of your branch names *at all*.
- Then, it runs a second Git command.  This *second* command will, or at least can, have some effect on some branch name.

  Which branch does this second command affect?  In theory, that could depend on the second command.  Which second command does `git pull` run?  That's under *your* control.

  You can choose to have `git pull` run `git rebase`.  If you don't do that, though, `git pull` will run `git merge`.  (There are some rare exceptions where `git pull` uses yet another option, but you won't hit those unless you're creating a new repository from scratch.)

  Before you see what `git fetch` fetches, you must decide in advance whether the new commits should be *merged*, with `git merge`, or *rebased-onto*, with `git rebase`.  Somehow, magically, you make this decision, and then you run `git pull --rebase` or just `git pull`, and Git runs the two commands.

  The *second* command affects your *current branch*, because both rebase and merge affect your current branch.  This is true no matter what options and arguments you give to `git pull`.

So your current branch matters.  And, every branch in Git can have one *upstream* setting.  If you run:

```
git pull origin new-branch
```

then `git pull` *ignores* the upstream setting (if any).  The name `origin` tells it where to `fetch`, and the name `new-branch` tells it how to run `git merge` or `git rebase` later, after the fetch finishes.

But if you run:

```
git pull
```

with no extra arguments, `git pull` uses the upstream setting.  This leads us to...

#### What an upstream is and does

Each branch name can have just *one* upstream setting.  Or, you can *unset* the upstream, and thus have no upstream.  If you unset the upstream—or have a branch in which it has never been set—running `git pull` with no arguments just complains at you.  So one thing setting the upstream does is enable you to run `git pull` with no arguments.

The upstream of a branch is just another name.  *Usually*, it's a *remote-tracking name* like `origin/master` or `origin/new-branch`.  This comes in two parts: the `origin` part—what `git pull` will give to `git fetch`—and the *name of the branch as seen in the other Git*.  Their `master` becomes your `origin/master`, so the remote-tracking name `origin/master` means, in effect, *their master*.

You can set the upstream of a branch to a branch in your own Git.  (Git stores this internally by setting the "remote" to `.`, but `git branch --set-upstream-to` doesn't need the `.`: you just do a `git branch --set-upstream-to=develop feature` and now the upstream of `feature` is `develop`.)  There are some small uses for this but for the most part, upstream settings should refer to some other Git.

Besides setting things up so that you can run `git pull` with no arguments—and also split this into `git fetch && git merge` or `git fetch && git rebase`, also with no extra arguments, if you want to split up the `git pull` like I often do—the upstream lets you:

- lets you see how far ahead and/or behind you are when you run `git status`; and
- affects `git push`, depending on your setting of `push.default`.

Some branch-creation commands automatically set an upstream for the new branch, and some don't.  For more details and links and so on, see [Why do I have to "git push --set-upstream origin <branch>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37770467/1256452) and [Why do I need to do `--set-upstream` all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6089294/1256452).