# How to set Upstream correctly and reversing changes in master branch to previous commit state?

Tags: git

I'm not very experienced with git so please bear with me

I made a mistake where I ran the command

```
git branch branchname --set-upstream-to=master
```

I thought this would sync my branch with master however I somehow put the all the changes that I had my in my branch to the master branch.

So my questions are how can I revert all the files on the master to the state they were in a previous commit?
As well as how do I properly sync so that I can get updated changes from master into my branch?

Answer (score 0):

First, relax a bit: `git branch --set-upstream-to=target branch` just sets the *upstream* of the branch named *`branch`* to *`target`*.  The upstream of a branch doesn't actually change anything about the branch.  What it does is change some *reporting*, and enable some shortcuts.

If you *acted on the reports*, that matters.  If not, it does not.

If you *used the shortcuts*, that matters.  If not, it does not.

To *remove* the upstream of branch B:

```
git branch --unset-upstream B
```

To change the upstream of branch B to `origin/B`:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/B B
```

> I thought this would sync my branch with master however I somehow put the all the changes that I had my in my branch to the master branch.

Again, this depends on any *other* commands you ran.  The `--set-upstream-to` option of `git branch` didn't do anything other than set the upstream.  For a discussion of what an upstream is about—what it's good for—see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37770744/1256452) to [Why do I have to "git push --set-upstream origin <branch>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37770467/1256452)

> So my questions are how can I revert all the files on the master to the state they were in a previous commit?  As well as how do I properly sync so that I can get updated changes from master into my branch?

Answering this is hard, because I think you're starting with some wrong assumptions.  This is very easy to do, because Git's system of branching is, well, downright *weird*.  If you've never used any other version control system before, you might not find it that odd, but if you have, Git can come as a big shock.

People like to think of branches as something *real*, something solid: useful, maybe immobile like a huge boulder, maybe sheltering like a building, and in any case, solid and reliable.  In other version control systems, they tend to *be* that way.  In Git, they're not: they're lightweight, ephemeral, fluid, and to a large extent, almost useless, in many ways.  They mostly do *one* thing for us, and they do that pretty well, but they don't do most of the other things we expect branches to do.  But here I'm talking about branch *names*, like `master` and `develop` and so on.  The word *branch* in Git is actually ambiguous: it doesn't always mean *branch name*.  The other thing it means *is* pretty solid.

(If you've never used any other version control systems, none of the above means very much, because you won't have prior expectations.)

#### Git is all about *commits*

Forget about branches for a bit here.  Git isn't so much about branches.  We use them, sure—they do something useful—but Git is really all about *commits*.  The commit is the basic unit in Git, and is the thing you need to know the most about.  So let's look at what a commit is and does.

**A Git commit holds data**—a snapshot of all of your files—**and metadata:** information *about* the commit.  That's what's in a commit: data and metadata; a snapshot of files, and some information about the snapshot, such as who made it and when.  Commits *don't* hold changes.  They just hold snapshots, plus that metadata.

**Once made, no commit can ever be changed.**  Not one part of any commit can ever change.  All of its files are frozen for all time.  This has a bunch of useful properties.  For instance, some people object to the fact that Git makes a new snapshot of *every* file for *every* commit.  Won't this make the repository get terribly fat, terribly fast?  Well, if Git did it the dumb way, it would; but Git doesn't, so it doesn't.

Let's say you have a hundred files.  You made a commit yesterday, with all 100 files in it.  You only changed two, and made a new commit just now.  98 of the files in the *new* commit match those in the *previous* commit.  Well, we just said that every commit is totally frozen—so your new commit can just *share* all 98 of the unchanged files.  It only really needs to snapshot the two *different* files.

The frozen files in each commit are further compressed, because they're in a special, read-only, Git-only form.  They're literally unchangeable in this form: it's not just *you* that can't change them.  Neither can Git itself.  This is great for archival, and it means that one answer to one of your questions is trivial:

> how can I revert all the files ... to the state they were in a previous commit

They're already in that state, in that commit.  All you need to do is use that previous commit.  But before we get to that, let's finish up dealing with what commits have in them.

**Every commit gets a unique number.**  A Git commit has a *hash ID*, and once you make a commit, that hash ID is forever reserved to mean *that* commit.  In a sense, it was reserved even before you made the commit.  However, the commit's hash ID is constructed by doing a cryptographic hash over all of the commit's data-and-metadata, and the metadata includes the exact second at which you create the commit, so we'd have to know in advance *when* you were going to create it, as well as everything else you were going to put into it, to predict its hash ID.

Every Git everywhere agrees that *that* commit gets *that* hash ID.  This means if you connect two Gits to each other, they can just look at each other's hash IDs: if your Git has their hash ID *H1*, your Git has their commit *H1*.  If they have your hash ID *H2*, they have your commit *H2*.  Wherever you have a hash ID they don't, or vice versa, you have a commit they don't, or vice versa.<sup>1</sup>  This makes exchanging commits pretty efficient: your Git knows which commits *they* have, and vice versa, just by looking at some hash IDs.

The last, but super-important, thing to know here is that **every commit stores the hash ID** (or multiple hash IDs) **of its immediate ancestor**: its *parent* (or parents, in the case of merge commits).  Note that this linkage goes only one way, from child to parent.  That's because when the child is "born"—when we make a new commit—we know what parent(s) we want to use.  But when we make a commit, we don't yet know what hash IDs it will have as children.  And, every part of every commit is completely, totally, 100% read-only, so we can't *add* the child hash IDs later.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git uses hash IDs for all four of its internal object types, not just commits, so this is a little bit off, technically.  The comparison is just *hash ID*, not *commit hash ID*; you have the *object*, or don't, if you have the hash ID, or don't.

---

#### [Let me sum up](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/31576i1AA9941F0B23A87F/image-dimensions/556x315?v=1.0)

So, Git stores *commits*, which:

- are snapshots of all your files, frozen forever,
- plus some metadata, such as who made the commit, when, why, etc.,
- and each one has a unique "number" (hash ID); and
- each one points back to its immediate parent, by storing the parent's hash ID.

These pointing-back links mean we can *draw* commits.  Let's start with a tiny repository with just three commits in it:

```
A <-B <-C
```

Commit `C` is the *last* commit, i.e., the one we made most recently.  It holds the hash ID of earlier commit `B`, so `B` is `C`'s parent: `C` points to `B`.  Meanwhile `B` holds the hash ID of earlier commit `A`: `B` points to `A`.  Commit `A` was our very first commit.  There is no earlier commit to point to, so it just doesn't.

Here, we're using single uppercase letters to stand in for commits.  But actual hash IDs are big and ugly and impossible for *humans* to work with.  They have to be big, so that you can get a unique one, different from every other commit hash ID, ever, every time you make a new commit.  So how will we remember that commit `C` is the *last* commit?

This is where *branch names* come into the picture.  In Git, a branch name like `master` just holds the actual hash ID of the *last* commit:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

(I've stopped drawing the internal arrows between commits as arrows, because it gets too hard.  Just remember, the arrows all point *backwards*; Git works backwards.)

If we have more than one branch name, each one just holds *one* hash ID.  Multiple names can hold the *same* hash ID:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, develop
```

Now we need a way to know which *branch name* we'd like Git to use, so we attach the special name `HEAD`, in all uppercase like this, to one of the branch names (just one at a time):

```
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD), develop
```

Here, we're *using* commit `C`, but *on* `master`.  If we now `git checkout develop`, we switch to commit `C`—i.e., we don't switch anything—but we also switch to *using* the name `develop`, so that we're *on* `develop`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, develop (HEAD)
```

If we now make a *new* commit, in the usual way—which I won't describe here—we get a new commit with a new big ugly hash ID.  Let's just call it `D`.  Commit `D` gets a new snapshot of *all* of our files, even if that just re-uses most of them from `C` (and note that if we change a file *back*, we'll re-use the copy from an older commit, so maybe `D` re-uses most of `C` and re-uses `A` or `B` for the last few files).  It gets its own metadata, including our name as the person who made it (the committer) and wrote it (the author),<sup>2</sup> and it stores commit `C`'s hash ID as its parent.  This is easy to do because the *branch name* `develop` has `C`'s hash ID in it right now.

Having made commit `D`, we now have:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, develop (HEAD)
       \
        D
```

and we're now at the *last* step of `git commit`, which is: it just writes whatever hash ID it just got, for the new commit, into the *current branch name*, i.e., the one to which `HEAD` is attached.  This causes the branch name to *move*:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

If we now `git checkout master` and make a new commit, we'll get a new commit `E` which will point back to `C`, and the name `master` will move:

```
        E   <-- master (HEAD)
       /
A--B--C
       \
        D   <-- develop
```

Note that we can, if we like, draw commit `D` or `E` on the same line as the first three commits.  The important thing is that we connect `D` back to `C`, and `E` back to `C`, and `C` to `B` to `A`.

The *graph* and the *commits* are real, and reasonably solid—the graph is flexible as long as we bend it without breaking any commits off—but the *branch names* are mere labels.  We can, at any time, tell Git: *take the label `develop` off commit `D`.*  We can make it point to *any* commit that we have.  We can even delete it entirely, though if we do that, we'll have a hell of a time *finding* commit `D`—its hash ID looks totally random, after all.

If we can't find `D`, Git will eventually remove it.  (Git has some safety measures to find temporarily-abandoned commits, usually for at least 30 days, in case you goof up.)  So commits aren't necessarily *forever*.  But once made, they can't be *changed*.  As long as you still have `D` and can find its hash ID, you have it, including all of its snapshot-files.

Note that we can find commits `A-B-C` in *two* ways at this point: we can start from `master` and find `E` and use that to find `C` and then `B` and then `A`; or we can start from `develop`, find `D`, and use that to find `C` and then `B` and then `A`.  This means that commits `A-B-C` are on *both* branches.  (This makes Git very different from most version control systems.)  If we *delete* the name `develop`, and can't find `D`, we can still find `A-B-C` and now they're only on *one* branch.  Or, we can add a new name:

```
        E   <-- master (HEAD)
       /
A--B--C   <-- three
       \
        D   <-- develop
```

and now commits `A-B-C` are on *three* branches, including the one named `three`.  Commit `C` is the *last* commit of `three`, and is part of—but not the last of—both `master` and `develop`.

This is what it means when I say that branches don't really mean very much.  What they do is allow us to find the *last* commit, and from there, we find all the earlier commits.  If we have another way to find those commits, the only thing the branch name is doing is remembering that some commit—like `C`—is the tip of *that* branch.

---

<sup>2</sup>This separation between *author* and *committer* allows Git to work with email, where someone just emails you patches that you apply.  You're then the *committer* and the other person is the *author*.  The Linux folks used Git like this in the early days of Git, and sometimes still do.

---

#### How you use all of this

Checking out a branch name means *select that branch's tip commit as the current commit* and *select that branch as the current branch*.  Git does this by:

- attaching the special name `HEAD` to the branch name; and
- extracting the frozen, read-only files from the chosen commit, into an area where you can see and work on them.

So, if you have:

```
...--F--J--K   <-- master
      \
       G--H--I   <-- branchname (HEAD)
```

and you've accidentally done something to add *new* commits to `branchname` that you don't want, such as adding commit `I`, you can just force Git to point the name `branchname` back to existing commit `H`:

```
...--F--J--K   <-- master
      \
       G--H   <-- branchname (HEAD)
           \
            I   [abandoned]
```

Commit `I` will stick around for a while—probably at least 30 days—but be invisible; you won't see it.  Once it's been hanging around too long, the maintenance garbage collector, `git gc`, will eventually remove it for real, and it will really be gone.<sup>3</sup>

To do this, you have to tell Git to forcibly re-set the name `branchname` to point to commit `H` instead of commit `I`.  There are multiple Git commands that can do this, but the main one you generally use for this is `git reset`.  This also wipes out any *uncommitted* work—well, depending on how you use it—and *uncommitted* work *cannot* be recovered for 30+ days, or for any days at all, so be *very careful* with `git reset --hard`:

```
git reset --hard <hash-of-H>
```

will do what we drew above, making commit `H` the current commit, and the name `branchname` point to commit `H`.  Commit `I` will still exist, but will be very hard to find again.<sup>4</sup>

---

<sup>3</sup>This assumes you didn't let some other Git copy commit `I` by its hash ID, into *their* repository, and thus grab it and keep it under some name of *their* choice.  If you did, they could later introduce commit `I` back to *your* repository.

<sup>4</sup>If you do decide you want it back, the usual way to find its hash ID is through Git's *reflogs*, which keep track of what hash IDs were in each *ref*.  But that's for another StackOverflow question.

---

#### Getting changes into another branch

> As well as how do I properly sync so that I can get updated changes from master into my branch?

Remember, *branches* aren't all that important.  It's *commits* that matter.  And, *commits* are snapshots.  They're not changes!  You can turn a commit *into* changes, though.  Pick any two adjacent snapshots—parent and child—and ask Git: *what's the difference in the parent snapshot, vs the child snapshot?*  That is:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

If we have Git extract snapshots `G` and `H` into two temporary working areas, then compare each *file* in the two temporary areas, we'll see what *changed*.  So that's what `git log -p`, `git show`, and `git diff` do.  The `git log -p` case takes each commit it's showing, as it goes backwards showing one commit at a time, and compares its parent to it—then goes on to show the parent, and so on.  The `git show` command takes one commit to show, shows it by comparing its parent to it, and stops.  With `git diff`, you can give it *any* two commit hash IDs; it extracts both commits, and compares them.<sup>5</sup>  It doesn't look at any commits in between: you just pick a left and right side, and compare.  You can compare your very first commit to your latest, if you like.

Two very useful Git commands are:

- `git merge`, which finds *three* commits, and does two `git diff`s and then combines changes; and
- `git cherry-pick`, which in effect *copies* a commit by comparing it to its parent, to make a set of changes out of it.<sup>6</sup>

When to use `git merge`, when to use `git cherry-pick`, and when and whether to use `git rebase`—which essentially runs a whole series of `git cherry-pick` commands for you—is another topic, and quite a big and often opinionated one.  I won't go into these details here.  Let's just show a real merge.  This occurs when you have two branches—this is where Git's ambiguity with the word *branch* is a problem—that looks like this:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1, merge-me (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

Note that our current branch name `merge-me` points to commit `J`, and `branch2` points to commit `L`.  We can now run `git merge branch2`.  Git will find commit `J` easily—that's our *current* commit—and find `L` easily, because the name `branch2` points to `L`.  Then Git will find the *best shared commit*, which Git calls the *merge base*.  In some cases it's not clear, but here, the best *shared* commit is obviously commit `H` (whatever its actual hash ID is): commit `H` is on *both* branches, and is the most recent such one, later than every other commit that's also on both branches.

So `git merge` will now `git diff` commit `H` vs `J`, to see what *we* changed on *our* branch.  It will also `git diff` commit `H`—the merge base, again—vs commit `L`, to see what *they* changed on *their* branch.  Then, Git will *combine* these changes.  If we changed file F in snapshot `H` to a new version of F in `J`, Git takes our changes.  If they also changed file F in snapshot `H` to a new version on `L`, Git takes *their* changes too.  The merge code combines the changes, if it can, and applies the *combined* changes to file F from snapshot `H`.

This repeats for every changed file.  For files where nobody changed anything—file F2 in `H` matches the one in `J` *and* the one in `L`—Git can take any of the three versions, because they all match.  For files where only one side changed anything, Git can short-cut: it can just take ours, or just take theirs.

The two diffs are run with `--find-renames`, to look for *renamed* files, and the diffs automatically look for files that were added or deleted.  The merge code combines these, too, or at least, as well as it can.

If our changes and their changes overlap, but aren't exactly the same, the merge code will declare a *merge conflict*.  In this case, Git will leave *all three input commit copies of the file* around.<sup>7</sup>  Git will also write its best effort at combining, with conflict markers where it had trouble, into your work-area.  Your job becomes *resolve these conflicts by producing the correct merge result.*  (You must then continue / finish the merge yourself.)

If Git doesn't detect any conflicts, though, Git will go on to make a new commit from the result.  Remember, this is the result of combining *all* the changes, and applying the *combined* changes to whatever was in the *merge base*—snapshot `H`, in our example:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- merge-me (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

New commit `M` is a *merge commit:* it points back to `J`, as any commit would, but also to `L`, the other commit that got merged.  (The fact that the merge used `H` as the merge base is not recorded anywhere.  If you ask Git *what was the merge base?* Git will just have to figure it out again, the same way it figured it out before `M` existed.)  The new commit `M` caused the *current branch* to advance to point to it, just as new commits always do.  Commit `M` has a snapshot—not changes—just like every other commit.  The *only* thing special about `M` is that it has *two* parents, instead of just one.  When Git works backwards through commits, one at a time, it must go from `M` to *both* `J` *and* `L`.<sup>8</sup>

---

<sup>5</sup>Because of the internal storage format, Git doesn't actually have to extract anything up until it gets to the point where two files really *don't* match.  In general, it doesn't need a temporary work area, it just does all this right in memory.

<sup>6</sup>Internally, Git actually implements `git cherry-pick` using the same three-way merge that `git merge` performs, but with the parent of the commit-to-copy as the *merge base*.  Afterward, instead of making a *merge commit*—a commit with two parents—`git cherry-pick` makes an ordinary single-parent commit.  But this explains why rebase is harder than merge: if you rebase a five-commit chain, you're actually doing *five* merges, instead of just one.

<sup>7</sup>These are in Git's *index* aka *staging area*, which I didn't go into here.

<sup>8</sup>This creates some interesting problems, since Git is going one at a time.  But again, these are for other postings.