# How to find the remote branch in git

Tags: git, github

I'd like to know How to find remote branch which will be pushed by `origin`

`git remote`

```
origin
```

`git remote -v`

```
origin  https://github.com/test/app (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/test/app (push)
```

I `cloned` from `develop` branch in `app`

`git clone -b develop https://github.com/test/app`

After that

`git checkout -b event-api`

`git branch`

```
develop
event-api
```

And then, I pushed like following.

`git push origin event-api`

This command pushed `event-api`　→　`develop`

But the `origin` seems `master` branch by `git remote`

```
①Why this command push to `develop` branch instead of master ?

②And How can I detect which branch will be pushed ?
```

If someone has opinion,please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `git push` command actually takes this as an argument.  Let's start with a more detailed command:

```
git push origin event-api:abc
```

This tells your Git that it should:

1. Call up some other Git at a URL you have stored using the name `origin`;
2. Offer it the last commit on your `event-api` branch, by that commit's hash ID;
3. Send any commits that the other Git asks for, based on the offer in step 2; and last
4. Ask the other Git to set *its* branch named `abc` to the commit offered in step 2.

That is, when you run `git push`, it's *your* Git that decides what to ask of the other Git.

Now, if you *leave out* the colon:

```
git push origin event-api
```

you might sensibly ask: *which branch is my Git going to ask their Git to set?*

The answer is complicated.  However:

> This command pushed `event-api`　→　`develop`

I have trouble believing this—to believe it, I'd have to see the exact output from your `git push` command.

Here is what [the `git push` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) has to say about this kind of `git push`.  Note that the `event-api` string, despite the lack of a colon and a second name, *is* a *refspec* in Git terms, and the paragraph quoted here talks about how refspecs are treated:

> The <dst> tells which ref on the remote side is updated with this
> push. Arbitrary expressions cannot be used here, an actual ref must
> be named. If `git push [<repository>]` without any `<refspec>` argument
> is set to update some ref at the destination with `<src>` with
> `remote.<repository>.push` configuration variable, `:<dst>` part can be
> omitted—such a push will update a ref that `<src>` normally updates
> without any `<refspec>` on the command line. Otherwise, missing
> `:<dst>` means to update the same ref as the `<src>`.

So, before we can say what `:<dst>` your Git will fill in, we must ask whether you have a configured `remote.origin.push` setting.  If you *do*, that determines which `:<dst>` is implied.

Most people *don't* have any such settings.  You have to be something of a Git guru just to find the information in [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), or to understand the paragraph quoted above, to know that there *is* such a variable.

If you *don't* have this set, which is what I suspect, then `git push origin event-api` is simply shorthand for `git push origin event-api:event-api`.  That is, your Git asks their Git to set (or create) their `event-api` branch.

If you run:

```
git push
```

without writing out `origin` and `event-api`, or:

```
git push origin
```

without writing out `event-api`, another set of rules take over.  Here, the most important questions—or at least the first two to ask—are: *What Git version are you running?* and *Have you set `push.default`?*

The `push.default` setting in Git version 2.0 or later is `simple`.  With `simple`, your initial push must generally use `git push -u`; after that, `git push` behaves sensibly, pushing your `event-api` to their `event-api`.  The reasons for this are a bit complicated, and you can choose other settings.  But in Git versions *predating* 2.0, which are still the standard versions installed by some Linux distributions, the default `push.default` setting is `matching`.

With the `matching` setting, a `git push` that *omits* the name(s) of *what branch or branches to push* works by having your Git ask the other Git which branches *they* have.  Let's say they have exactly two branch names, `master` and `develop`, while you have three branch names, `master`, `develop`, and `event-api`.  So their Git will list out `master` and `develop`.  Your Git then goes through your three names and matches each against the two names they sent.  The result is the two names they sent.

(If you had deleted your `master` and/or `develop`—which is something you can do; there's no requirement that your Git have any branch names in particular—then you'd have one or zero matching names in this step.  But presumably you have these three names, and they probably have just those two.)

Your Git will now, in step 2, offer the last commit on your `master` branch, and offer the last commit on your `develop` branch.  These are the two matching names, so these are the two commits your Git will offer.  Their Git will probably already have those commits, but if they don't, they will, in step 3, ask for those commits, and any other commits required to support those commits.

In any case, having gotten through steps 2 and 3, your Git will now ask the other Git to *set* its `master` and its `develop` to the two hash IDs from your own Git's `master` and `develop` respectively.  If this makes no changes, you see nothing at all here, but if you did have new commits for them, your Git will send those commits in step 3, and you will see one or both names get updated in step 4.

#### What to remember here

Remember these things about `git push`:

- Your Git calls up another Git.  To do this, it needs a URL.  You will generally use a name like `origin` here; `origin` is a *remote* and a remote stores a URL.
- Your `git push` then pushes *commits*.  Specifically, your Git needs commit hash IDs.  Your Git gets these hash IDs from *your* branch names, which need not match the other Git's branch names.  We humans tend to use matching branch names for our own sanity: Git doesn't really care, but we do.
- Having sent some commit or commits if needed, your `git push` ends by sending the other Git one of the following:

  - A polite request: *Please, if it's OK, set your branch name ______ to commit hash ID ______.*
  - A command: *Set your branch name ______ to commit hash ID ______!*
  - A conditional command: *I think your branch name holds hash ID ______.  If so, set it to hold ______ instead.*

  In all three cases, they tell your Git whether they did it, and if not, why not (which your Git prints as a "rejected" error).

The arguments in `git push remote refspec...` are the *remote*, which supplies the URL, and the *refspecs* (one or more of them), which supply both the local commit hash ID—based on a name, usually, but you can use a raw hash ID if you want—and the name *they* should set on their end.

(If you do use a raw hash ID, you may have to send a fully-qualified name, like `refs/heads/event-api`, as there's now no easy way for your own Git to guess whether you mean the name as a *branch* name, a *tag* name, or some other kind of name.)

If you omit the colon in a refspec, the branch name your Git will ask their Git about is normally *the same name you used*.  However, several configuration settings, such as setting `push.default` to `upstream`, can change this.  If you *do* use the `upstream` setting, the control here is what you have set for the branch's *upstream*.  See [Why do I have to "git push --set-upstream origin <branch>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37770467/1256452)

Answer (score -1):

```
git branch -r

git branch commands’ various options. -a shows all local and remote branches, while -r shows only remote branches.
```