# How to track an existing repo's branch and call it my own?

Tags: git, branch, branching-and-merging, git-clone

I am working with two repos: `originalRepo` and `copyCatRepo`.

`originalRepo` is a repo managed by a third party which has a branch that I'd like to 'copy'. I want my `copyCatRepo` to have a master branch which tracks all changes of `originalRepo/branch_eight` so that if `originalRepo/branch_eight` receives any updates while I am working in my `copyCatRepo/master`, I can update my `copycatRepo/master` to have those new changes.

How do I set up a branch in my `copyCatRepo` to track all changes in a different repo's branch? All I am trying to accomplish is add a patch to an external repo but I need to be aware of changes.

Answer (score 0):

`git config pull.rebase true` and set a remote to pull from the origin and push to your github.

Answer (score 0):

> ... I want my `copyCatRepo` to have a master branch which tracks all changes of `originalRepo/branch_eight` ...

You'll probably want to create multiple *remotes*.  A remote is primarily a name by which Git remembers the URL of some *other* Git repository.  The first standard name for a remote is `origin`, and that's a good one.  The *second* standard name is `upstream`, and that one is confusing, because a branch also has an *upstream*, and these are different things.

You'll want to set the *upstream* of your `master` branch to something unusual, and otherwise use `git fetch`, `git merge`, and/or `git rebase`.  To run fetch followed immediately by either merge or rebase, you can use `git pull` as in [jthill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65397927/1256452).

I'll go into more detail here after the long part below.

## Long

This answer is pretty simple, but does not really make any *sense* until you realize that Git isn't *about* **branches**.  Git is, instead, all about **commits**.  Branch names like `branch_eight` and `master` *are* useful, but their use is that they *find* commits.  It's the commits themselves that actually matter.

With that in mind, let's take a look at what a repository really is: it's a collection of commits (and other internal Git objects that commits need), plus a collection of names—branch names, tag names, and other such names.  We'll concentrate on just two things *about* a commit here, as we look at this.

Each commit has a unique number.  This number is expressed as a big ugly string of letters and digits, such as [`3cf59784d42c4152a0b3de7bb7a75d0071e5f878`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3cf59784d42c4152a0b3de7bb7a75d0071e5f878).  These things look random (but aren't), and are unpredictable.  Each new commit has to get a new, totally-unique hash ID, which is why they have to be so big and ugly.

Most of the bulk of most Git repositories consists of a big database: a simple [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database) with hash IDs as keys, and commits and other internal Git objects as the values.  Git needs to know a commit's key—the hash ID—to *find* a commit in the database.  So commits have these unique hash IDs.  But, even though each one of these is the "true name" of each commit, they're completely unsuited for use by mere humans.  So each Git repository contains a *secondary* database, which is another key-value store where the keys are *names* like branch names, and the value stored under any given key is a single commit hash ID.

This one hash ID is all we need, because every commit stores, inside itself, the hash ID(s) of some *previous* commit(s).  Most commits store exactly one previous-commit hash ID, which Git calls the *parent* of a commit.

Whenever you make a new commit, you start with some existing commit.  (Obviously there's a bootstrap problem here, getting the first commit in; we'll ignore that.)  Then you make the new commit, and its parent is the commit you started with.  So the commits themselves form a simple backwards chain.  A *branch name* just holds the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain, like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

Here, the *name* holds the hash ID of the *last* commit, which has some big ugly hash ID but we'll just call it commit `H`.  Commit `H` itself holds a snapshot and metadata (which we didn't cover properly) and includes the actual hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  Commit `G` holds another snapshot and metadata, including the hash ID of still-earlier commit `F`, and so on.

We say that the commits *point to each other*—always backwards, because that's just how Git is—and that the branch name points to the last commit.  To add a new commit to a repository, we create the new commit, pointing backwards to what *was* the last commit in the chain, then move the *name* **forwards** to point to the new last commit:

```
... <-F <-G <-H <-I   <--master
```

That's all it takes to add one commit to a repository: add the new commits—the existing commits never change; in fact, they *cannot* change—and update some name or names to find the new "last commits".

Branching happens when you build stuff like this:

```
             I--J   <-- br1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             J--K   <-- br2
```

To get here, we added a `br1` name *also pointing to `H`* and then added two commits, one at a time, advancing the name `br1`.  Then we added a `br2` name *also pointing to `H`* and then added two commits there.  The commits up through `H` are on *all three* branches.

(Not shown here: how `HEAD` works, by attaching to just one *branch name*.  That's your current branch, and then the commit that the branch name points-to is your *current commit*.)

#### Branch names are not the only kinds of names

Besides *branch* names, each repository can store other kinds of names.  All the names go into the names-database.  When necessary, Git can distinguish the *kind* of name by using the *full* name: a branch *`B`* has a full name `refs/heads/B`.  The other two kinds of names that you'll deal with regularly are *tag names*, which have full names starting with `refs/tags/`, and *remote-tracking names*, which have full names starting with `refs/remotes/`.

The remote-tracking names are your own Git repository's way of remembering some *other* Git repository's *branch* names.  If they have a branch *`B`*, and you use the name `origin` to *reach* their Git repository, your Git will store their *branch* name *`B`* using your *remote-tracking name* `origin/B`.

Just like branch names, all of these names just point to one commit.  (Tag names have a complicated way of doing this, called *annotated tags*, while remote-tracking names are simple like branch names, because they're literally just copied from branch names.  You don't need to worry about the extra complexity of annotated tags here.)

The key difference between a *branch* name and one of these other names, besides of course the prefix part of the full name, is that you can get "on a branch".  When you do, and make new commits, Git will *automatically update your branch name* to point to your new commit.  But when you work with a *remote-tracking name*, the way to use its commit gets you into what Git calls *detached HEAD* mode.  That's because Git won't let you get "on" a remote-tracking name.

People don't like to work in detached HEAD mode (for good reason: it's not a good idea in general, it's for special cases like being in the middle of an unfinished rebase).  So in general, when we're working with one or more *remotes*—other Git repositories as found by names like `origin` and `upstream` and whatever names you want to make up for them—we humans like to create corresponding *branch* names.

#### Clones and the standard naming conventions

The usual first remote name, as I mentioned earlier, is `origin`.  You don't even have to set this one up yourself: just running `git clone` does it for you.

The `git clone` command is essentially just a convenience command.  It runs five or six other commands for you, with the first one being a non-Git command and the rest being Git commands:

1. `mkdir`, or whatever your OS uses to create a new empty directory (folder).  The remaining commands run *in* this folder, although when they're done, you have to move to it manually (for OS-specific reasons).

   As a special case, you can tell `git clone` to build the clone in an existing empty folder, in which case it skips the `mkdir` step but still runs the Git commands in that folder.  Unless it's `.` you generally have to `chdir` or `cd` into it afterwards.
2. `git init`, which creates a new empty Git repository.  This new repository has *no* commits and *no branches*.
3. `git remote add origin url`: this adds your first remote, named `origin`.  You can pick a different name with a command line option, but if you don't, you get the standard name.  Git saves the URL under the name, and arranges for their *branch* names to become your `origin/*` *remote-tracking* names.
4. `git config`, if and as needed: you can get extra configuration set before step 5, if necessary, using command line options.
5. `git fetch origin`: this has your Git call up the other Git, using the stored URL.  Their Git shows your Git all of their branches and other names, and your Git uses these to copy *all their commits*.  Your Git *does not create branch names* though: instead, your Git turns their *branch* names into your *remote-tracking* names.

   When this step finishes, you have a repository that has *all of their commits* and *none of their branches*.  Of course, the remote-tracking names are just as good as branch names, in terms of *finding* commits.  But it's important to realize that all the *names* you have here are remote-tracking names.
6. `git checkout` (or, in Git since 2.23, `git switch`—which does the same thing here).  This *creates* one branch name.  The name it creates is the one you told `git clone` to use, with your `-b` option.  If you didn't specify a `-b` option, your Git asks the other Git which branch name *they* recommend, and uses that name.

It's this last step—step 6—of `git clone` that makes your first and only branch name, in your new clone.  It's super-common to use the name `master`, although it's becoming more common (because of GitHub) to use the name `main`.  The important thing here is that the *name* is a *branch name* that the *other* Git was using, that is now a *remote-tracking* name in your own repository.  Your Git creates a new branch name for *your* repository, using the same spelling as their Git uses for *their* branch name.  But *your* Git is using your *remote-tracking* name, set up in step 5, to do this.

You end up with the same name for your branch as for their branch, but your Git has gone through all this crazy shuffling, from branch names to remote-tracking names, back to a (single) branch name, to get there.  You need to be aware of this, because you're going to have *more than one remote*.

#### More about `git fetch`

Our description above just said that `git clone` runs `git fetch` as step 5.  It's the `git fetch` step that:

- figures out which commits they have, that you don't, that you need;
- gets their *branch* names and turns them into *remote-tracking* names;
- gets their commits and adds them to your repository; and
- creates and/or updates your remote-tracking names based on their branch name hash IDs.

For that first `git clone`, you had *no* commits, so this first bullet point is easy: you need *all* of their commits.<sup>1</sup>  But you'll run `git fetch` again later, and/or to other Git repositories.  When you do, the set of commits that you need is often *much smaller* or even totally empty.

Remember that, earlier, I said that each commit gets a totally-unique hash ID.  This hash ID is *always the same in every Git repository*.  That means your Git can tell whether some other Git's commit is the *same commit you already have*, or not, just by looking at the hash ID.  So when you run `git fetch origin` later, if they haven't added any new commits, your Git can very quickly find this out, and not bother getting any new commits.

Note that they can add new *branch names* without adding new commits.  For instance, they can make two names point to the same commit.  This is entirely normal: it is how new features get written.  We start by making a new branch name that points to some existing "last commit".  So your `git fetch` might create or update *remote-tracking names* without getting any *new commits*.

The fetch command's job, in other words, is two parts: **get any new commits** (commits they have, that I don't, that I want); and **update my remote-tracking names** (so that I remember which commits their *branch* names pick).

---

<sup>1</sup>There are some exceptions here, e.g., for shallow and/or single-branch clones, and there are lot of details I'm glossing over on purpose to keep the description simple.  The reality is much more complicated.

---

#### Adding more remotes

To add a new *remote* to your existing Git repository, you will run `git remote add name url`.  The *`name`* you pick here is arbitrary and is up to you.  The use of `upstream` is kind of standard, but as I mentioned above, it's annoying in one way.  Every Git *branch* in your own repository can have one *upstream* setting.  You can set the upstream of a branch to whatever you want, whenever you want.  This has little if anything to do with a remote named `upstream`, whether you have one or not.

I find it confusing to talk about the upstream of `master` *and* the remote named `upstream` at the same time.  So I'm not a big fan of this as a standard second name, myself.  But this part is up to you.  Here, I'm going to call this second remote `xyzzy`, after the [magic word in Colossal Cave Adventure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossal_Cave_Adventure#Xyzzy):

```
git remote add xyzzy <url>
```

Having done this, you then need to run `git fetch` to it:

```
git fetch xyzzy
```

This will call up another Git, at the specified URL, as before.  You'll get, from that Git, any commits they have, that you don't, that you need—this might be as few as *no* commits at all—and then your Git will create (or update, but this is the first time, so "create") *remote-tracking names* for each of their *branch* names.  If they have a branch named `master`, you will get an `xyzzy/master`.

#### This breaks the special trick that clone used (though clone got there in time)

Note that at this point, you will probably have:

- `master`: your own branch, matching origin/master at the moment;
- `origin/master`: the remote-tracking name in your Git from `origin`'s `master`;
- `xyzzy/master`: the remote-tracking name in your Git from `xyzzy`'s master
- `xyzzy/branch_eight`: the remote-tracking name in your Git from `xyzzy`'s `branch_eight`

The key issue here is that *there are now two remote-tracking names that are from `master`*, one being `origin/master` and the other being `xyzzy/master`.  The special trick that `git clone` used in its step 6, to create your `master` from `origin/master`, *stops working at this point*.

That's not a problem for your *existing* `master`, which already exists.  It's a problem for *new names*.  Suppose that both `origin` and `xyzzy` have a branch named `feature`, and you decide that now, you would like to create a new `feature` based on one of those two.  You run:

```
git checkout feature
```

and your Git complains.  The problem is that it doesn't know whether to use `origin/feature` or `xyzzy/feature`.  There are *two* names that could match.

This is just a minor headache.  You can still use an automatic trick:

```
git checkout --track origin/feature
```

will create `feature` based on `origin/feature`.  You give it the remote-tracking name, and Git figures out which part is the branch part (`feature`) on its own and creates your feature branch.  Or, you can use:

```
git checkout feature origin/feature
```

which does exactly the same thing.<sup>2</sup>  The disadvantage is that you have to type the word `feature` twice.  The advantage is that you can use a different *branch* name, e.g., `git checkout feat37 origin/feature`.

Both of these have, as a Git built-in thing, the side effect of creating the new branch with its *upstream* set to the remote-tracking name, in this case `origin/feature`.

**This is also the case with your existing `master`.**  Its *upstream* is set to your own `origin/master`.  Read on for what this all means, but before we get to that point, let's note one last problem.

Suppose you'd like to have your own `feature` corresponding to `origin/feature` *and* your own feature corresponding to `xyzzy/feature` too.  (Let's assume these are two different features, and you are going to work on both of them.)  *You can't call both of these `feature` in your own Git repository.*  You'll be forced to make up a *different* local branch name for at least one of these.  This isn't particularly harmful in and of itself, but it makes for a bunch of small headaches later.  Just be aware of this for now, as the problem may never actually come up.

---

<sup>2</sup>Well, it does the same thing *by default*.  There are configuration settings you can change, that make these slightly different.

---

#### What good is an upstream anyway?

Rather than answer the whole thing here, I'll just link to this: [Why do I have to "git push --set-upstream origin <branch>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37770467/1256452)

The big plus-es here are the ability to run `git rebase`, `git merge`, `git fetch`, and the convenience `git pull` commands without typing anything else into the command line.  It also makes `git push` slightly more convenient—but for your particular use case, it might actually make `git push` slightly *less* convenient.

You will need to think about this (and/or experiment with setting the upstream, or unsetting it entirely if you like) and see what works *for you* as there's no universal best way here.

## Your own use case

Given your setup, I'd recommend:

- making sure your Git is at least 2.15, if not newer, if you're going to use `git worktree`;
- cloning one of the two repositories and adding the other as another upstream;
- using `git worktree add` to create extra work-trees for rebasing branches other than the current branch, if you find you need to do that.

Set or unset upstreams of various branches in whatever way works for you.  Remember to use `git fetch` to get updates.

Consider configuring `fetch.prune` to `true`:

```
git config --global fetch.prune true
```

so that if some remote *deletes* some branch *`B`*, your `git fetch` to that remote, via name *`R`*, deletes `R/B` from your own remote-tracking name set.  Without this, "stale" remote-tracking names build up: `git fetch` sees that they have a branch named `tmp` and creates, say, `origin/tmp` in your Git, then they delete their temporary branch `tmp` and your `git fetch` finds no `tmp` so does not create or update your `origin/tmp`.  This leaves your *old* (stale) `origin/tmp` behind!  The more remotes you have, the more likely this kind of stale-remote-tracking-branch clutter becomes.

Last, remember that Git repositories share *commits* (by their big ugly hash IDs), but each repository has *its own* branch names.  The fetch operation gets commits and updates remote-tracking names; but a push operation *sends* commits, then asks *their* Git to set *its branch name*, which generally requires that your new commits add on to their existing commits.