# What config does `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master` actually update?

Tags: git

When you run:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

what config does it actually update under `.git`?

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37770467/1256452).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It updates the `.git/config` file of your current repo, setting `remote` and `merge` properties under the specified branch:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = <branch>
```