# Git: i forgot create branch master, how i can create it if my repository already has another branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch

I got an issue with my repository but i have no solution to resolve it. Please correct me.

I created a repository on bitbucket, cloned it and got message **"You appear to have cloned an empty repository"**. Next, i created new branch **my-feature** with command **git checkout -b my-feature** and added some code. Finally, i push to remote repository with command **git push --set-upstream origin my-feature**. All done, but i just realized that my repository has no branch master. Now, it has only branch **my-feature**.

***How i can create branch master but still remain **my-feature** branch (that means i don't want to create new repository)?***

Comment: Just do `git push <remote> <branch>` i.e. `git push origin master` and it will be available in remote. Your local repository has the **master** branch, you just need to push it to remote.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this may resolved my issue. But this way may bring all commit from my-feature to master. How i can create master branch that it does not take any commit from my-feature branch (or an initial commit with only file composer.json)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have now is a Git repository—or rather, two very similar repositories; we'll just think of it as one for now—with just one branch name, `my-feature`.  *This is not an error situation.*  There is no requirement that any Git repository have a branch name `master` in it.

Still, if you'd like to have a branch name `master`, all you have to do is create one.  There's nothing special about the name `master`.<sup>1</sup>  **A branch name in Git is just a way to find one specific commit.**  Git is not *about* branches.  Git is all about commits.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, *almost* nothing: there are a bunch of little random bits of stuff here and there.  For instance, most *humans* will assume that the name `master` means something.

---

#### Git is about commits

To understand what's going on here, and why this is OK as is but you can create a `master` whenever you like, let's look at how Git really works.  Again, Git is all about *commits*.  So the main thing to know is what a commit is, how we find them, and how they accumulate in a repository.

- The first thing to know is that *every commit is numbered*.  These numbers are really big and ugly looking and weird: they don't simply count up like 1-2-3.  For instance, [this commit is numbered `71ca53e8125e36efbda17293c50027d31681a41f`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/71ca53e8125e36efbda17293c50027d31681a41f).  The number on any given commit is totally unique to that one commit.  If you had this commit in your Git repository, it would have this same number.  If you don't have this commit—and you don't because it's a commit for Git, in a Git repository for Git—then you don't have any commit with this number.

  The uniqueness property is *why* these numbers are so big and ugly.  They're computed by running a cryptographic hash function over the contents of the commit.  This has a consequence: the number is deeply attached to the contents, so the *contents can never change*.  No part of any commit—any internal Git object, really—can ever change, because its number depends on its content.  This is the magic: this is how two different Git programs can agree that only *this* commit gets *this* number.<sup>2</sup>

  Because the numbers come out of a hashing function, they are called *hash IDs*.  Because the original hash function was (and still is for now) SHA-1, they're also called *SHA-1 IDs* or *SHA-1s*.  Because Git is in the process of going to still-larger hashes, Git is changing the internal name from *SHA1* to *OID*, or Object ID.  (Commits are one of four internal object types, and all of them use this same hashing system.)

  I mostly call these *hash IDs* myself, but be aware of the other names.
- The other thing to know is that each commit stores two parts:

  - The main data of a commit is a *snapshot of all the files Git knew about at the time the commit was made.*  We won't go into the details of the source of the snapshot here, but it's not your working tree, it's the thing that Git uses three names for: the *index*, the *staging area*, or the *cache*.  All names refer to the same thing.
  - Besides the snapshot, each commit contains some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  This includes the name and email address of the author of the commit, for instance, with a date-and-time-stamp for when the commit was made.  The log message you enter, explaining *why* you made the commit, goes here; you'll see that log message in `git log` output.

    Crucially for Git, Git sticks something in this metadata for its own use.  Each commit stores a list of the hash IDs of some *earlier* commit or commits.

    Most commits store just one hash ID, for one earlier commit.  We can call these *ordinary commits* to distinguish them from commits that have no earlier hash IDs, or two-or-more earlier hash IDs.  At least one commit—the very first one—literally *can't* store any earlier commit hash ID, so it just doesn't; we call that one the *root commit*.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>2</sup>The [pigeonhole principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) tells us that this scheme must eventually fail.  The number of bits in the hash ID is designed to make it such that the failure is so many trillions of years in the future that we don't care about it.  [There's a small flaw in this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452), but it's fine for now.

<sup>3</sup>A repository can have more than one root commit, but this is at least a little bit unusual.  We won't get into the details here.

---

#### Hash IDs are too klunky: enter *branch names*

Let's draw a simple repository that has just three commits in it.  Rather than their actual big ugly hash IDs, we'll call these three commits `A`, `B`, and `C`—and we'll draw them like this:

```
A <-B <-C
```

Remember that each one holds a snapshot and some metadata.  Commit `C` is the *last* of these three commits, so it's the most recent and, in a way, the most important.  Inside commit `C`, we have the latest snapshot, in a read-only form.  We also have the metadata, including the hash ID of earlier commit `B`.  Let's be "on" commit `C`, but use this hash ID.

Inside commit `B`, we have the snapshot and metadata, including the hash ID of earlier commit `A`.  Without yet going *to* commit `A`, we can *compare* the files saved in both `B` and `C`.  All of the files that are *the same* are uninteresting, but for files that have *changed*, we can show the changes.  That's pretty useful—so that's what `git show` or `git log -p` will do, if we're on/using commit `C`: it will show the *changes* from `B` to `C`.

If we use `git log`, we can now have Git go *back* one step, from `C` to `B`.  Now we have a snapshot and metadata, including the hash ID of commit `A`, but this time we'll go ahead and look up commit `A`.  By comparing its snapshot to that in `B`, we can see what *changed*.  So `git log -p` can print the log message for commit `B`, then show the *changes* from `A` to `B`.

Once again, we can have Git step back one hop, to commit `A`.  Commit `A`, being the very first commit, has no earlier commit: its list of previous commit hash IDs is empty.  So commit `A` is our root commit, and all the files in `A` are "new".  The `git log -p` command will just show them as new files, and since there's no *earlier* commit, it will stop here.

Note that Git works *backwards*.  This is generally true of all things in Git: they always work backwards, from latest towards earliest.  The reason for that is those embedded hash IDs: they look like arrows pointing backwards.  We start with commit `C` because it's the *most recent* commit.  We do, however, have to know the hash ID of commit `C`.

We could write down the hash ID of the latest commit.  We could keep it on a scrap of paper, or a whiteboard, or whatever.  Starting from the end, we tell Git to look at `C`, and Git can find all the *earlier* commits on its own.  But this seems silly.  We have a *computer*.  Why not have the *computer* keep the hash ID of commit `C` somewhere?

**This is what a branch name does.**  A branch name simply holds the hash ID of the *latest* commit that is part of that branch.  We can draw that like this:

```
A <-B <-C   <--branch
```

To make a *new* commit, we have Git package up a snapshot and metadata.  The metadata for our new commit, which we'll call `D`, will include the actual hash ID of commit `C`, as found by reading the hash ID stored under the branch name `branch`.  So new commit `D` will point back to existing commit `C`:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D
```

(I've gone to lines instead of arrows because I don't have good graphics for arrows here.  We know nothing inside any commit can change, and the arrows coming out of commits always point backwards, and come out of the commits, and hence can't change where they point.  So the lines work just as well, as long as we remember that Git can't follow them *forwards*, only backwards.)

Now that commit `D` exists and has a hash ID—computed by hashing all the stuff in the commit, including the date-and-time-stamp for when we *created* commit `D`—now we can have Git write that hash ID into the *name* `branch`, so that the *name* points to commit `D` instead of commit `C`:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D   <-- branch
```

and now we can straighten the whole thing back out again:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- branch
```

#### Branch names find commits, regardless of how many branch names there are

Let's start with our three-commit setup again, without having made `D` yet.  Let's call the first name `main` (as GitHub usually do now) instead of `master`, though in fact, any name will do fine.  Let's draw that, but this time I want to add one more thing to our drawing:

```
A--B--C   <-- main (HEAD)
```

The new thing is this `HEAD`, in parentheses.  We have this to mark *which branch name we are using*.  Right now there's only one name, so there is only one name we *can* use, but we're about to change that by adding a new name.

Now let's create a new name, `develop`.  **We must pick some existing commit** to make this name exist, because a branch name is *required* to point to some existing commit.  So let's pick commit `C`, which is the latest on `main` and is the commit we're using right now.  We run:

```
git branch develop
```

and get:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop, main (HEAD)
```

Note now both branch names point to commit `C`.  This means commit `C` is the last commit on *both branches*.  That's perfectly fine, in Git; it means *all three commits* are on both branches, too.

The special name `HEAD` is still attached to `main`, so we're still actually *using* the name `main`.  Let's run `git checkout develop`, which does this:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop (HEAD), main
```

We're no longer using the *name* `main` as our current *name*.  It still exists and still points to commit `C`, but now `HEAD` is attached to the name `develop`.  That name also points to commit `C`, so nothing else has to change, and nothing else *does* change.  We're still "on" commit `C`, but now, we're "on" it because we're "on" the name `develop`.

Now we'll make our new commit `D` as before.  Git will package up everything and write out a commit, which gets a new, unique hash ID.  (If we put in exactly the same files, use exactly the same commit message, and make it at exactly the same *time*, we'll get the same hash ID we got last time—but if the *time* is different, or anything else has changed, we'll get a totally different hash ID.  I'm still going to call it `D`, though.)

As the last step of committing, Git will update the *current branch name*, but now that's `develop`, not `main`, so now we get:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        D   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

We still have two branch names; we still have `HEAD` attached to `develop`; but now we have a new commit `D`, and the *name* `develop` picks new commit `D`.

We can now switch to the latest `main` commit with `git checkout main`, which picks commit `C`, or the latest `develop` commit with `git checkout develop`, which picks commit `D`.

Note that the files *in* each commit are read-only, frozen in their form at the time, for all time.  This means Git has to copy the files *out* of the commit, so that we can use and change them.  We won't go into detail about this here, but it's something to keep in mind: the files you see and work with are *not in the repository!*  They're **copies**, *extracted from* the repository.

#### How you got into this situation: branch names can't exist without commits

When you started out, you used Bitbucket to create an empty repository.  Drawing an empty repository isn't very interesting:

There are no commits, and for a branch name to exist, it *must* point to some *existing commit*.  There aren't any!  So no branch names can exist either.

You then cloned this empty repository, making a copy on your machine.  When you did that, you got a warning:

> ```
> You appear to have cloned an empty repository
> ```

Git gives you this warning because you're in this same weird state: with no commits, no branch names can exist.

Despite the fact that no branch names *exist*, Git still requires that the special name `HEAD` be "attached to" the current branch name.  What happens in this case is that Git shoves an initial dummy name into the internal `HEAD` file, so that `HEAD` is attached to `master` or `main` or whatever name you pick as your default initial branch, or give to `git init` if you have one of the new versions of `git init` that takes a name argument.

At this time, you can run `git checkout -b` as much as you like.  Each one will shove a new name into the special `HEAD` name.  That branch name continues not to exist, *and* continues to be the *current branch name*, in this weird special state in which you're on a branch that does not exist.

So, when you ran:

> ```
> git checkout -b my-feature
> ```

you told your Git to set up your empty repository so that you were on the non-existent branch named `my-feature`.

**When you make the first commit in this state, this creates the branch.**  The first commit anyone ever makes in an otherwise empty repository is a *root commit*, with no earlier commits:

```
A   <-- my-feature (HEAD)
```

This first commit, which we can call `A` regardless of what hash ID it gets, has no parent, so it just sits there.  But now there is a commit!  Now there can be a branch name!  In fact, now there can be infinitely many branch names.  They all just have to point to `A`.  That's the only commit, so all branch names must point here.  Let's make a branch `xyzzy` here by running `git branch xyzzy` (which uses the current-and-only-available commit):

```
A   <-- my-feature (HEAD), xyzzy
```

Once you create a *second* commit `B`, you have two commits:

```
A   <-- xyzzy
 \
  B   <-- my-feature (HEAD)
```

You can continue to create new branch names, and this time, you can pick either commit `A`, or commit `B`, to have them point-to.  So now you can make a `master` that points to either `A` or `B`.

#### What you need to do now

All you have to do now is pick some existing commit.  Run `git log` to get a list of your commits, on your (single) branch `my-branch`.  If there's only one, that's the only one available.  If there are more than one, those are the ones available.  Pick some available commit and tell `git branch` to put a branch name there.  Let's say that one of the available hashes is `a123456`.<sup>4</sup>  Then run:

```
git branch master a123456
```

and Git will create, in your own repository, the name `master`, pointing to the existing commit whose hash ID starts with `a123456`.

You can also use `git checkout -b master hash`, which means *create the name, then attach to it*.  If you leave out the hash ID, both `git branch` and `git checkout -b` assume that you mean to use the *current commit*, as found by using the special name `HEAD`.

Now that you have the *name*, use `git push` to ask the Git over on Bitbucket to create the *same name* in *their* repository, using the same hash ID:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

The `--set-upstream` is sort of optional, but will do something you want.<sup>5</sup>

---

<sup>4</sup>An actual hash will be long and difficult to type in.  Use cut-and-paste with the mouse, or something, to grab the whole thing, or just type the first four or more characters.  If you type in something that resembles the first part of a hash ID, Git will try to figure out if that's short for a longer hash ID that starts with what you've typed in.

<sup>5</sup>See [Why do I have to "git push --set-upstream origin <branch>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37770467/1256452)

Comment: Hi @torek, thank you for your explanation. so i wrap up that master it is just a branch with no special. So my issue become easy to resolve. Thank you!