# Following git fetch and reset, wrong remote is the default

Tags: git, github

I have `upstream` and `origin`.  I'm currently not using origin, and updating everything to upstream only.  The only branches locally or on either remote are `main`.

I did `git fetch upstream` followed by `git reset --hard upstream/main`.  That had the desired effect of making my local the same as the last commit from the upstream remote.

But now when I commit I'm getting:

```
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 7 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

I don't want to use origin at all and previously I wasn't getting this message when committing.

How can I solve this?  I've tied my repos in knots before by hacking at little things like this so want to do it right.

Comment: `git branch -u upstream/main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A local branch can be configured to track a remote branch. (What you call "the default.") This puts them in an automatic relationship for push, pull, and news about who is ahead.

Your `main` is tracking `origin/main` and it always was. Your `git reset --hard upstream/main` didn't change that, but it did put your `main` out of phase with `origin/main`, so now you're getting automatic news about the difference.

If you don't want automatic news about `origin/main`, set your `main` to track `upstream/main` instead:

```
git branch -u upstream/main
```

Or just turn off the tracking entirely:

```
git branch --unset-upstream
```

If you do that, you will have to be more verbose when you push or pull, but you will be in less danger of the wrong thing happening automatically.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37770744/341994 for a good explanation.

Comment: In my opinion you should take the second option and unset the upstream completely, because you have put yourself into a complex situation (two remotes) with no clear understanding of what you're doing. The less automatic behavior, the better.