# What does git pull when having different branches?

Tags: git

Suppose I have two branches in my git repository: A and B.

Then, I switch to branch B:

`git checkout B`

If I do:
`git pull origin A`

Am I incorporating remote changes of branch A into the current branch B?

or

Am I updating only the branch A, incorporating the remote changes of A into the local branch A?

Comment: If you want to update A while you have B checked out you'd do `git fetch origin A:A`

Comment: Pull means fetch, then merge. Think about it.

Comment: just read the very first sentence of the git documentation:
"Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch. "
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

so if you say origin A you are telling git to incorporate changes from A to your current branch.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

You are getting the equivalent of:

```
git fetch origin A && git merge origin/A
```

which merges your current branch `B` with whatever the `git fetch` did to your `origin/A`, which depends on what happened in their `A`.

## Long

This gets a little bit complicated.  Here's the **best way to think about it and remember how it all works**.

The basic command has this form:

```
git pull [<options>] [<remote> [<refspec> ...]]
```

where the square brackets indicate that something is optional, e.g.,:

```
git pull --ff-only origin branch-A
```

specifies all three but:

```
git push origin branch-A
```

leaves out the `<options>` part.  The angle brackets, meanwhile, mean *fill this in with something*, which is why we replaced `options` with `--ff-only` (a valid option) and why we put in `origin`—a valid *remote*—and `branch-A`—as valid *refspec*—as our remote and refspec options.  Finally, the three dots `...` mean *you can keep adding more of these*, in this case, more *refspecs*.

That still leaves you with some **extremely important questions**.  We'll use simple answers here to try to keep things simple; there are more details that I will leave out:

- What options can we use?  What do they all mean?
- What's a *remote* and what's a *refspec*, why don't we have to provide them, and what do they do when we do provide them?
- What does all this do anyway?

There are many options, but there are two or three you should know: `--rebase` and its counterpart, `--no-rebase`; and `--ff-only`.  We'll come back to these.  Let's move on to remote and refspec, and what this all does.

#### What is a remote?

In brief, a *remote* is a short name you will use for *some other Git repository*.  Your own Git repository is just that: a Git repository.

A Git repository is, at its heart, really just two databases:

- One database holds *commits*—which save every file for all time, more or less—and supporting things called "objects".  These are all *numbered*, with big ugly hairy scary-looking *hash IDs* or *object IDs* ("OIDs") like <sub><sup>`cefe983a320c03d7843ac78e73bd513a27806845`</sup></sub>.  These things are pretty toxic, or at least indigestible, to human beings, so we try to avoid using them.  But they're how Git actually *finds* the commits.
- The other database holds *names*.  These are things like branch names, tag names, and many other special-purpose names.  **Each name translates to exactly one of those big ugly hash IDs.**  They help you—and Git—find the commits that *you* care about.

Because Git acts as a big *distributed* database, we connect our own Git software, working with one Git repository of our own, to someone else's Git software (such as on GitHub for instance), working with one other repository.  That other repository might be nominally "ours" ("our fork on GitHub"), or someone else's ("their fork" or whatever).  Either way though, we have our-software-with-our-repo ("our Git") talking to their-software-with-their-repo ("their Git").

To connect our Git *to* their Git, we have to give our Git a *URL*, like `https://github.com/user/repo.git` or `ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git` or something.  Our Git (our software running on our repo) uses the URL to reach their software, and point it to their repo, so this URL locates "their Git".  These URLs are long and typo-prone and generally not great for humans, so we have a convenient *shorter* name.  That's a *remote*.

This remote—this short name for some other Git—lets us hook our Git up to their Git easily.  We just say `git fetch origin` and our Git looks up `origin` and gets the URL.  We say `git push origin` and our Git looks up `origin` and gets the URL.  Or we say `git pull origin`, and our Git looks up `origin` and, well, you get the idea.

**The remote, then, is the short name for the other Git.**  The name `origin` is the *standard* short name for the other Git you used when you ran `git clone url` to create your repository the first time.  At that time, your Git software created a new, totally-empty repository, then set up the standard first name `origin` to *store* the URL, in this new empty repository.

**Then your Git ran `git fetch origin`.  This got, from the `origin` Git, all of their commits and other objects, and all of their names—the contents of the two databases.**  But here's tricky part number 1:  **Your Git doesn't keep all of their *branch* names.**  Instead, your Git *renames* all of their *branch* names, sticking `origin/` in front of them.<sup>1</sup>

So in your two Git databases—commits and supporting objects, and names——you get *all of their commits* and *none of their branches*.  Instead, what they had as *branches*, become your *remote-tracking names*.  A remote-tracking name is like a branch name, but with the name of the remote stuck in front, plus the slash.  That's where `origin/main` or `origin/master` comes from, for instance.

As a last step, `git clone` then *creates one branch name* in your own repository.  Typically, we run `git clone` without the `-b` option.  If you use the `-b` option, you're telling your Git which of their branch names to use here.  But usually we don't, so your Git asks their Git which branch name *they* recommend.  They'll generally recommend their `master` or `main`, and that's the branch name *your* Git will create.

Since the point of branch names is to help us find *commits*, which have those big ugly hash IDs or OIDs, your Git makes your one new branch using the *same OID* that *their* Git used for their recommended branch.  So, assuming they recommend `main`, your `main` will now match your `origin/main`, which will match *their* `main`.

This is all pretty confusing at first.  It takes a while to get a good handle on it.  The key here is that *your branches are yours*.  Meanwhile *their branches are theirs*.  Your Git will take their *branch* names and *rename them* to be your *remote-tracking names*.  And **it's not actually the names that matter**, but rather the hash IDs (or OIDs) of the commits.  You'll use your names—your branch names *and* your remote-tracking names—to find the right hash IDs: your most recent commit, or their most recent commit, for instance.  They'll use *their* branch names to find the right commits.  Every once in a while, you have to synchronize these things.  How often, when, and how ... well, we'll get into this in just a moment.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, this isn't quite right, but it's good enough for here.

---

#### `git fetch`

You asked about `git pull`, but we should start instead with `git fetch`.  The fetch command is the more basic one, and is what Git tutorials should start with.  None of what `git pull` does makes any sense until you first understand `git fetch`.

The `git fetch` command takes a *remote:* the name of some other Git to call up.  Its purpose is to *get updates for your databases*, and to get those updates, it has to call up some other Git software talking to some other Git repository, using a Git URL.

If you don't *give* `git fetch` a remote, it will find one on its own, or—as a last resort—default to `origin`.<sup>2</sup>  By a bit of magic,<sup>3</sup> Git will usually get this right, so you don't *have* to name `origin` anyway, but you might want to, as we'll see.

Your Git then uses the stored URL to call up some other Git.  That other Git, as before, has its own two databases, with commits-and-supporting-objects and with names.  Your Git gets, from their Git, all the names and the latest commit hash IDs.  Your Git then checks to see if you have these commits.  If you *don't* have them, your Git asks their Git to send over those commits.  The two Gits have a conversation here where your Git figures out what commits they have, that you don't, that you'll need.  They then package up the commits and any other supporting objects and send them over:

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 1400, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (679/679), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (55/55), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (297/297), 104.28 KiB | 1.13 MiB/s, done.
```

The messages starting with `remote:` came from some software *on* the remote (in this case, supporting Git software) as it packed up objects.  The messages *not* starting with `remote:` are from your own Git software.  At the end of this process, I now have 297 new objects, some of which were commits, in my objects database.  (This is a clone of the Git repository for Git, which I updated quite recently, but it's pretty active.)

Now that your *objects* repository is updated, your Git will take any of their *branch* names that have changed since the last update, rename them to remote-tracking names as usual, and update *your* names database with these updated remote-tracking names:

```
From [url]
 + 3ecb51dcfc...6839d98bf9 seen       -> origin/seen  (forced update)
```

In this case, `seen` was *their branch name;* `origin/seen` is my *remote-tracking* name.  (I'll skip over the `forced update` part here.)

In summary, then:

- `git fetch` gets, from their Git, new commits and other objects, by name.
- `git fetch` brings these over and puts them in your objects database, then updates tags and/or remote-tracking names, by default.

So: **`git fetch` updates your Git from their Git, but does not do anything to any of your *branch names*.**  (That is, not by default, and not with anything I'm going to show here.)  You get your *remote-tracking names* resynchronized with *their* branch names.  You get any new commits they have, that you don't.  And that's it: the fetch is all done.

If you have more than one *remote*, you can run `git fetch remote1` and then `git fetch remote2` and so on, to get new commits from `remote1` and update `remote1/*`, and then to get commits from `remote2` and update `remote2/*`, and so on.  Most people have only one remote anyway though, so one `git fetch`, with nothing else listed, suffices.

If the `origin` repository is very large and/or very busy, and your network connection is very slow and you need something *right away*, you might want to *limit which of their branches you synchronize*.  In this case, you would run:

```
git fetch origin branch-A
```

to update your `origin/branch-A` and nothing else, or:

```
git fetch origin branch-A branch-B
```

to update your `origin/branch-A` and your `origin/branch-B`, but nothing else.

This uses what are called *positional arguments:* the word `origin`, the *remote*, goes in the left-hand position, and then everything after it is one of their *branch names*.  **You cannot leave out the remote** because `git fetch branch-A branch-B` means *using `branch-A` as a remote, fetch just the one branch `branch-B`*, which probably doesn't work anyway.

As it turns out, a branch name, as we're typing them in right here, works just fine as a *refspec*.  So this also answers the *what's a refspec* question, at least in part:<sup>4</sup> branch names work just fine as refspecs here.<sup>5</sup>

---

<sup>2</sup>Git may be growing a facility for changing this default first remote name, along with a facility for changing the default first *branch* name from `master` to `main` or whatever, so someday, this might be more complicated.

<sup>3</sup>The main magic here is that most people only have one remote anyway.  The secondary magic is that Git will read the remote name from the *current branch name*.

<sup>4</sup>Technically a refspec consists of:

- an optional leading `+` sign; then
- two *refs* separated by a single colon `:`, or one *refs*.

A *ref* is a fully-spelled-out name, like `refs/heads/branch-A` or `refs/remotes/origin/branch-A`.  We're not going to use either the leading `+` sign *or* the pair-of-refs thing here, as `+` means "force" and careless use of full refspecs can mean "wreck my branch names".  Accidents here are often recoverable, but we don't want to get into a situation where they can occur in the first place.

<sup>5</sup>In very old versions of Git, predating 1.8.4, there's an issue with refspecs and `git fetch`, in that Git omits what Git calls *opportunistic updates* of remote-tracking names.  But surely you're using a modern version.  (You can check with `git --version` if you like.)

---

#### `git pull` *runs* `git fetch`

The reason you really need to understand `git fetch` before you get into `git pull` is that `git pull` *means:*

1. run `git fetch`; then
2. based on what happens in step 1, run another Git command.

It's the `git fetch` step that gets new commits from some other Git, puts them in your repository, and updates your remote-tracking names.  **It's crucial to understand this before we move on.**  The reason we move on to run a second command is simple, though: as we just learned, `git fetch` *does not affect any of your branches at all*.  (At least, not the way we use it here.)

Presumably one of the reasons you're going to some other Git to get new commits from them is that you'd like to *use* those new commits.  And, presumably at least, you then *want to update some local branch(es)*.<sup>6</sup>  This is where that second Git command—that step #2—comes in.

**The `git pull` command offers you your choice of two primary second commands.  The two commands people use here are `git merge` and `git rebase`.**  You *need to know which one `git pull` will run*.  You can control this with the options I mentioned:

```
--rebase
```

tells `git pull` to run `git rebase` second, and:

```
--no-rebase
```

tells `git pull` to run `git merge` second.<sup>7</sup>  The *default*, if you don't pick one of these two, is something you can configure.  If you haven't configured it, the *default default*, as it were, is to use `git merge`.

The thing is, you now need to learn about *both* rebase *and* merge.  So let's touch on them lightly.  Both commands can get very complicated, and I cannot cover them thoroughly here.

---

<sup>6</sup>It's possible to work Git with *no* local branches.  In some situations this might even be advisable.  But it's not how most people actually use Git.

<sup>7</sup>You might wonder why this isn't `--merge`.  It probably should be, but the reason it isn't is historical: originally `git pull` *only* ran `git merge`.  So, once Git learned to be able to run rebase second, that was the `--rebase` option.  Then people wanted a way to make rebase the default.  So *that* got added to Git too, and then people wanted a way to override their rebase default, so that became `--no-rebase` ... and that is where we are today, October 2021.

---

#### `git merge`

The merge command and the merging system is quite central to Git.  Git is a *distributed version control system*, where a version control system lets us keep multiple versions of various files.  Since Git is a *distributed* one, that means many people may be keeping many versions of many files.  At some points, now and then, we need to *combine work* that different people did.

**The merge system, build around a *merge engine*, is all about doing this: combining work.**  The `git merge` *command* invokes the merge engine *sometimes*.  It's not the only way to invoke the merge engine, and it doesn't always use it, but when it does use the merge engine, it uses it in the simplest, or at least easiest-to-describe, way.

Without covering all the important details, we'll start with a rough illustration of a series of commits.  Remember that the actual "names" of commits are big ugly hash IDs—each commit gets a *unique* hash ID, never to be re-used<sup>8</sup>—so we'll use uppercase letters like `H` to stand in for some `H`ash ID.  We'll draw a few commits with earlier commits on the left, and later commits on the right:

```
          I--J   <-- feature (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- alice/feature
```

The *names* here, `alice/feature` and `feature`, are the names we see in our own Git repository.  We made a remote named `alice` and used it to get commits from Alice.  She made *her* commits, `K` and `L`, on *her* branch named `feature`, at the same time we were making *our* commits `I` and `J`, on our branch `feature`.  The `HEAD` in parentheses here is how we draw the fact that we're on our branch `feature`, hence using commit `J`.

If we now run `git merge alice/feature`, our Git will figure out what we both *started with*—that's the set of files saved forever in commit `H`—and from that, what *changes we made* in which files when we made our commits `I` and `J`.  Git will, separately, figure out what *changes Alice made* in her commits `K` and `L`.

The merge engine will now do its best to *combine our changes and Alice's changes*.  If Git's merge engine succeeds at doing this combining—or even *thinks* it succeeds; Git isn't smart, and is just following a bunch of simple text rules here—Git will then use the *combined changes*, as applied to the snapshot saved in commit `H`, to make a new snapshot:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- feature (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- alice/feature
```

This new snapshot goes into a new *merge commit* `M`, which causes our current branch `feature` to advance one commit, the same way any new commit we make, makes our current branch advance one commit.

Meanwhile Git's successful (presumably—we'd best *test* this) combining of our changes and Alice's changes has (presumably) produced something better than either of our features on its own, so we should send commit `M` to Alice so she can use it.  That's where `git push` will come in, but we won't cover that here.

*Some* merges, though, are trivially easy.  Suppose we and Alice start with the same set of commits:

```
...--G--H   <-- feature (HEAD), alice/feature
```

We're using commit `H`, and so is Alice.  Now Alice makes her two new commits (which we'll call `I` and `J` this time).  We run `git fetch alice` and get them:

```
...--G--H   <-- feature (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- alice/feature
```

If we now run `git merge alice/feature`, our Git says to itself: *Huh, look at that, we don't have any commits of our own... why, we can just switch straight to Alice's commit!*  So it does that, giving us:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I--J   <-- feature (HEAD), alice/feature
```

(There's no reason to draw in the kink in the graph any more either, so we can put this all on one line, if we like.  I didn't bother here.)

Git call this operation a *fast-forward merge*.  Running `git merge --ff-only` tells Git: *If you can do it as a fast-forward, do a merge.  If not, give me an error.*

**Fast-forward merges have one big advantage: they don't create a new commit.  They have one big disadvantage too: they don't create a new commit.**  Sometimes you want that, and sometimes you don't.  (There's no room in this answer to say when.)  You can force Git one way or the other, with `--ff-only` or `--no-ff`.

---

<sup>8</sup>This is mathematically impossible.  The size and ugliness of hash IDs is the way it is to put doomsday as far as possible into the future.  For various reasons, even Git's current hash ID size, which was intended to be good for at least thousands of years, is getting to be too small, and hash IDs will be getting even bigger and uglier someday.

---

#### `git rebase`

If you have no commits of your own, and you get new commits from Alice, you can use `git merge --ff-only` to avoid making new merge commits (if you're one of those people, or in one of those situations, where you don't want merge commits).  But what if you and Alice both *do* have new commits?

```
          I--J   <-- feature (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- alice/feature
```

You can, if you like, use `git rebase` to *copy your old `I-J` commits to new and supposedly-improved ones*.  That's what rebase is really all about: it copies some set of existing commits to new (and supposedly improved) new commits.  This *can* get very fancy, but when it works automatically and is used in the simplest way, the result looks like this:

```
          I--J   [abandoned]
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- alice/feature
              \
               I'-J'  <-- feature (HEAD)
```

Note how the new (and improved, if they're actually improved) commits `I'` and `J'` extend not from commit `H` but rather from commit `L`, Alice's latest.  That is, we used to both add on to commit `H`.  But now *we* add on to commit `L`, so that Alice's commits remain exactly as-is.

This process really does abandon our original two commits: commits are *completely read only* once they're made, so it is *impossible to change the original two*.  But what if commits `I` and `J` have two big ugly hash IDs that nobody knows, and their improved replacements `I'` and `J'` have two different big ugly hash IDs that nobody cares about, and everyone—which really means "just us", probably—*finds* these two commits using the *name* `feature` in *our own Git repository?*  Who's even going to *know* that we ever did this?

Nobody, that's who.  Well, we might remember.  Or not!  It's easy to forget that you've done a rebase, or even multiple rebases.  That's kind of the point here.  We rebase to replace our existing commits with new-and-improved ones.

The actual mechanics of copying an old commit to a new-and-improved one involve using `git cherry-pick` or similar, and that in turn uses Git's *merge engine*.  So if we rebase two commits, that's like running `git merge` twice, in a way.  If we rebase ten commits, that's like ten merges!  The number of "merge" operations, or at least pseudo-merge operations, grows linearly with the number commits we have to copy.  *Each step* can have a merge conflict.  So it's not a good idea to just keep rebasing forever: eventually you and Alice should get together and agree that some of your commits go into *her* repository too, or you start merging, or something.  But sometimes, rebase is just what you want.

#### `git pull`

Now, at last, we can cover `git pull` *properly*.  It:

1. runs `git fetch`; then
2. runs a second Git command: you pick, rebase or merge, before you even get a chance to see what step 1 does.

Having somehow, in advance, picked *which* command you want, you then run:

```
git pull [<options>] [<repository> [refspec]]
```

Note that I've left out the more-than-one-refspec option, and I'll explain why in a moment.

You've already configured, with `git config` or whatever, your *default* for whether `git pull` should run rebase or merge second.  If you haven't, you've chosen `merge` by default.  If you definitely want rebase this time, add `--rebase` here to your options.  If you definitely want merge this time, add `--no-rebase` here.  If you want your default, leave both out.

Add any additional options to pass to rebase or merge.  We haven't covered any rebase options here, but we have mentioned two *merge* options: `--ff-only` and `--no-ff`.  If you definitely want a fast-forward merge *if* fast-forwarding is possible:

```
git pull --no-rebase --ff-only
```

will make sure that happens.  If a fast-forward *isn't* possible, the second command—the `git merge` step—will simply *fail* and you can choose what to do then.  If you definitely want a merge even if fast-forwarding *is* possible:

```
git pull --no-rebase --no-ff
```

will make sure *that* happens.

If you want or need to add a *refspec*, you must now first stick in a *remote*.  That's because the remote and any refspecs you provide will be passed to `git fetch`.  The fetch command treats these as *positional arguments*, so you can't:

```
git pull branch-X          # error
```

You have to:

```
git pull origin branch-X   # OK
```

The `pull` command will pass both arguments to `git fetch`, so you'll call up the remote named `origin` and get from them just any update they have to `branch-X`.

**Now here's why you should use only one refspec**, i.e., just one branch name: if you choose merge, `git pull` will take the *`remote`* argument out and *pass remaining arguments through* (changing branch names to remote-tracking names first of course).<sup>9</sup>  We didn't cover this above, but:

```
git merge alice/feature1 alice/feature2 alice/feature3
```

performs what Git calls an *octopus merge*, merging all three of Alice's commits, found via these three remote-tracking names, into your *current branch*.  If you don't know what an octopus merge is, you definitely don't want one.  (Later, once you learn what one is, you probably *still* won't want one.<sup>10</sup>)

If you're using rebase, the rebase operation *can't* take extra remote-tracking names (or technically hash IDs) like this, so you *can't* run this kind of rebase.  That is, `git pull --rebase alice feature1 feature2 feature3` is automatically an error.

---

<sup>9</sup>Technically, what `git pull` passes to `git merge` here are raw hash IDs.  Or, in the latest versions of Git, where `git pull` has been rewritten as C code, this is done with direct function calls, rather than literal text strings.  It works out the same though.

<sup>10</sup>They don't do anything you can't do without them.  In fact, at least as I see it, their value—such as it is—is that a *regular* merge is *more powerful* than an octopus merge, so that if someone spots an octopus merge in a repository, they can assume that it was a set of simple merges.  [Even this can be abused though.](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17326904)

---

#### Conclusion

The things to take away here are:

- `git pull` *means* "run fetch, then run a second Git command".  The `fetch` step takes the remote *and* the refspec; the second command uses *the commit that the fetch step found*.
- The second Git command is one of `git merge` or `git rebase`.<sup>11</sup>  This *affects the current branch only*, not any other branch.
- You *do not want* an octopus merge, so do not use `git pull remote branch1 branch2 branch3 ...`.  The result is *not what you wanted*.
- If you omit the *`remote`*, the default is as for `git fetch`.
- If you omit the *`refspec`*, the default is the *upstream setting* for the current branch.

We have not covered the *upstream setting*.  See [Why do I have to "git push --set-upstream origin <branch>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37770467/1256452) and [Why do I need to do `--set-upstream` all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6089294/1256452)  You don't *need* to set an upstream, but once you do, it's convenient: among other things, it lets you run `git pull` without having to type in a remote and a branch name.

(I personally never liked the "run two commands without letting me check stuff first" thing, and tend to use `git fetch` and then a separate second command *after* I see what `git fetch` fetched.  However, recent Git has `git config --global pull.ff only`, which makes `git pull` do what I usually want, so I'm trying to adapt to that now.)

---

<sup>11</sup>There's a special case when you're on an *unborn branch*, but you won't care about this.  In ancient Git, this case could ruin your week (I had that happen to me), but that's long fixed.

Comment: OK so am I the only one who wants to know what bad thing happened if you did a git pull when on an unborn branch????

Comment: @matt: Git ran a `git checkout -f` that wiped out all my files. The code base is so different now that it literally can't do that, but that was a very bad several days. (I was on an unborn branch in a repository I'd made and never added-or-committed-to yet, if I remember right, when I remembered to go make the repo on the server and then just unthinkingly ran `git pull origin master`. It was long enough ago that I'm not sure how it chose to extract the empty tree, but that's what it did...)

Comment: I think I'll just commit before saying _anything_ to Git from now on.