# git commands working on windows command line but not in Git Bash terminal

Tags: windows, git, cmd, git-bash

I'm working on remote repository with git commands on windows cmd and it works well, but when working with git commands in git bash terminal I get error:

```
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/feature/branch-name'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

How can I fix it for git bash terminal?

Comment: As a sidenote, `feature/` is part of the `branch-name`.

Comment: Yes, when I work on some tasks I create a new branch to work on this task, in this case it's branch-name, and after finishing the task I make pull request to the main branch

Answer (score 2):

Check first, in your git bash session, the ouput of:

```
git branch -avv
git status
```

Make sure the name of the branch you are in matches the remote one, especially considering the case (uper/lowercase), in case it is insensitive in a CMD session, and sensitive in a bash session.
See [this example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/611234/7490).

If the list of branches show the local one is not linked to a remote tracking one, then, as I documented in "[Difference between `git checkout --track origin/branch` and `git checkout -b branch origin/branch][2]`":

```
git branch -u origin/branch branch
```

Comment: For the first command it prints the list of available branches and
for the second command it prints:
```On branch next
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/next'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean```

Comment: @Sakén can you edit your question with the exact output of the list of branches from the first command?

Answer (score 1):

It started working when I moved to the main branch (next).
But, when i switch back to my branch this is what I get:

```
$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> feature/branch-name
```

Finally found the answer here:
[Why do I have to "git push --set-upstream origin <branch>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770467/why-do-i-have-to-git-push-set-upstream-origin-branch)

```
git push -u origin <your-local-branch-name>
```

So if your local branch name is coffee

```
git push -u origin coffee
```