# Create a remote branch of a remote repository

Tags: git, github

I have started a job as a front end dev and have been instructed to use my predecessor's git workflow for the time being.

He was creating a remote branch, tracking master, for sprints (so sprint-01(remote) tracks master) and then branching again locally (sprint-01(local)) to make changes. The remote sprint-01 deploys to a staging website - no development is done on a local server.

The issue is I do not know how to create a remote branch of a remote depository.

So far I have tried

```
git remote add -t master sprint-01 <URL>
```

and it's not showing up in the branch list the way previous sprints have; I get:

```
master 
remotes/origin/master
```

when listing branches.

However, when I enter command git remote -v I get:

```
origin  <URL>(fetch)
origin  <URL>(push)
sprint-01    <URL>(fetch)
sprint-01    <URL>(push)
```

What I'd like is to get another branch in the usual way but remote:

master
   remotes/origin/master
   remotes/origin/sprint-01

I am currently running through in depth git tutorials but we are starting a sprint on Tuesday and would like to be able to join the workflow without issue even if I haven't found the answer in documentation by then. Thank you stack community.

Comment: It seems to me that you mix up branches and remotes. Do you want to create a banch on origin, or do you just want to add a remote?

Comment: Is it not possible to create a new branch off of a remote repository which is also remote? So let's say I have a git repository at a server under azure admin. I checkout to origin master branch and then git branch -b spint-xx. When I make changes, the changes are still recorded on the remote server and not my local machine.

My understanding is that whether something is local or remote makes little difference - you should be able to branch or fetch from anywhere and to anywhere...is there something fundamental I am missing?

Comment: local or remote makes a (quite) big difference. having a local branch (newly created with checkout -b) does not presuppose where you will push it (on the origin remote or another one). Thus creating a branch on a remote is just a matter of creating a local branch and then push it to the remote (whatever remote it is).

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR summary

*Commits* are shared (by copying) between different Git repositories.  *Branches* are *not* shared: when you run `git fetch`, your Git asks some other Git about its branches, and then your Git creates *remote-tracking names* like `origin/master` to remember *their* branches.  This has no effect on your branches!

You can also run `git push`, which has your Git call up their Git and ask them to create or update *their* branches, which again has no effect on your branches.  But, a successful `git push` has your Git update *your* Git's remote-tracking names, since your Git's remote-tracking names remember where *their* Git's branches go.

#### What you did

You have created a new *remote*.  A remote is a way for your Git to remember the URL of some other Git, and along with that, to remember some or all of *their*—the other Git's—branches, at least, as of the last time your Git talked with their Git.

By default, `git remote add` asks *your* Git to record, under some name, the URL for some other Git.  That's *all* it does by default, so:

```
git remote add them <url>
```

just has your Git remember `<url>` under the name `them`, so that you can—***later***—run `git fetch them` or `git push them` without having to type in a long URL again.

Adding `-t` tells your Git that it should not just record the URL, but also change the way that your Git will talk with their Git in the future.  Normally, your Git would call up their Git and have them list *all* their branches, then copy *all* those names to your remote-tracking names.  That is, after:

```
git remote add sprint-01 <url> -t master
```

(you can shuffle the `-t` more towards the front, as you did), the *next* `git fetch` call your Git makes to their Git will go like this:

- **YOUR GIT:** Hi `them`, what branches do you have?
- **THEIR GIT**: I have `master`, `dev`, and `feature-123`.
- **YOUR GIT:** I don't care about `dev` and `feature-123`, but give me any `master` commits you have that I don't.
- *Insert long conversation about hash IDs—now that your Git knows their `master` hash ID, everything happens by hash ID.  Once your Git knows which hash IDs they have that you don't, your Git has them send you all the commits and any necessary files and so on, as well.*
- *Last, after your Git has the commits you need, your Git creates your `sprint-01/master` to remember their `master`.*

Note that nowhere in this process has *your* Git ever asked *their* Git to create any branches.  Nor, for that matter, has your Git created any *branches:* at the end of the `git fetch` conversation above, your Git creates your `sprint-01/master`.  (The full name of this thing is `refs/remotes/sprint-01/master`.)  That's your Git's way of remembering their Git's `master`.  Your Git sticks `sprint-01/` in front so as to remember that it came from the *remote* that you called `sprint-01`: `sprint-01` is the name you're using to remember the URL for their Git.

#### What you wanted to do

You probably already have a remote, remembering the URL of another Git.  That remote's name is `origin`.

You'd like to have your Git call up their Git and start a rather different conversation:

- **YOUR GIT:** Hi `origin`, I'd like you to create a new branch named `sprint-01`.  Make it point to *(some particular commit hash ID)*.
- **THEIR GIT:** OK, done.
- **YOUR GIT:** 'kthxbye!
- *Now that your Git has seen that their Git has created `sprint-01`, and knows which commit hash ID your Git asked them to use, your Git creates, in your repository, the remote-tracking name `origin/sprint-01`.*

The tricky part here is the phrase *some particular commit hash ID*.  Where will you get this hash ID?  The only hash ID your Git *can* use is *the hash ID of some commit you have in your own repository*.

Typically, the *way* you choose the commit hash ID is to look through the commits you have in your repository and choose one of them as the *right* commit that *they* should also use as *their* `sprint-01`.  You might use `git log` to find this commit, for instance.

You then create *your own branch*, using that commit hash ID:

```
git branch sprint-01 <hash>
```

or:

```
git checkout -b sprint-01 <hash>
```

If no commit is suitable because you need a *new* commit, you first create your own `sprint-01` from some existing commit hash ID:

```
git checkout -b sprint-01 <existing-hash>
```

and then make for yourself the new commit that *is* suitable, in the usual way of making any commit.

Then, in any case, you now have, in *your* Git, a branch named `sprint-01` that points to the desired commit hash ID.  This may be some existing commit—which they probably already have—or some new commit that you just created, whose parent hash ID is some existing commit that they probably already have.  You can now simply run:

```
git push origin sprint-01
```

to have your Git call up their Git, offer them new commits if necessary, and then ask *their* Git to create *their* `sprint-01` branch, pointing to the *same commit hash ID* that yours uses.

#### Terminology: or, *tracking* is a badly-overloaded verb

> He was creating a remote branch, tracking master, for sprints (so sprint-01(remote) tracks master) ...

This doesn't quite make sense, as stated.

Git has a problem with its terminology.  I've used the phrase *remote-tracking name* to describe strings like `refs/remotes/origin/master` (or `origin/master` for short).  A *remote-tracking name* is a name in *your* Git repository whose purpose is to remember the hash ID stored under *their* Git's *branch* name.  Git calls this a *remote-tracking branch*, but it's not actually a branch, because you can't get *on* it the way you can a real branch:

```
$ git checkout origin/master
Note: checking out 'origin/master'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. ...
```

Note the somewhat-scary stuff about "detached HEAD" here.  All this really means is: *you're not on any branch now.*  Running `git status` will show you, among other things, `HEAD detached at ...`.  But:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

Now `git status` will say `on branch master`.

A branch, then, is something you can *get on*, by running `git checkout branch-name`.  You can't "get on" a remote-tracking name like `origin/master`, so we shouldn't call it a *branch*.  The longer phrase "remote-tracking branch" has the word "branch" right there in it, so it's not a good phrase.  (But Git uses it, so keep in mind that a "remote-tracking branch" is not a *branch* even though it has the word "branch" in it!)

Now, a branch—but not a *remote-tracking name*—can be set to have what modern Git calls an *upstream*.  You can have one, and only one, upstream, for each of your branches.  To set the upstream of some existing branch, run:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=<upstream> <branch>
```

Typically, the upstream of the branch `master` is `origin/master`.  The upstream of your `dev` or `develop` would be your `origin/dev` or `origin/develop`.  The pattern here is clear: usually, you want the upstream of your (local) branch *`X`* to be (your) remote-tracking name `origin/X`.

To make it so that a branch has *no* upstream, run:

```
git branch --unset-upstream <branch>
```

It's never *necessary* to `--unset-upstream`, but sometimes you might want to.  See [Why call git branch --unset-upstream to fixup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21609781/1256452)

When a branch like `master` has `origin/master` set as its upstream, Git says that `master` is *tracking* `origin/master`.  Note that this *tracking* verb applies to the *local* branch name.  You can set the upstream of one of your (local) branches to another *local* branch, too:

```
git branch foo                           # create a new local branch named foo
git branch --set-upstream-to=master foo  # set its upstream to master
```

You *cannot* set an upstream for a remote-tracking name:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=master origin/master
fatal: branch 'origin/master' does not exist
```

This is correct: *branch* `origin/master` does not exist; only *remote-tracking name* `origin/master` exists.<sup>1</sup>  What this means is that a remote-tracking name cannot track anything, in the sense in which the verb *track* is used for branches!  This is true even though it's a remote-tracking name: as a remote-tracking name, it's just *automatically updated* when you run `git fetch`, based on what your Git learns from the other Git.

This same verb *track* gets applied to files, too: some files are *tracked* and others are *untracked*.  This particular kind of tracking has nothing to do with branches!  A file is tracked if and only if it is in Git's index.  The index is very important, but has nothing to do with branch names and remote-tracking names, so all I will say here is that you can put files into, or take files out of, the index at any time, which means that whether some file is *tracked* is something you can control; there are crucial consequences to this when you run `git commit` because `git commit` makes new commits *from* the index, rather than from the work-tree.

Now that we know that *tracking*, for a branch, means *has an upstream set*, let's look at this again:

> (so sprint-01(remote) tracks master)

If `sprint-01` is a local branch, it can track another name like `master`, but if `sprint-01` is a remote-tracking name, it cannot track any other name.

If you mean that, when you log on to the remote and `cd` to that repository, *that* repository has a (local) branch named `master`, well, *that* repository's (local) `sprint-01` can certainly track any other name inside that repository—but that repository's branches are *theirs*.  Their Git does not control the branch names in *your* repository, and any upstream set there is not even *visible* to your Git!  So *this* statement—that `origin`'s `sprint-01` is set up on `origin` so that it tracks `origin`'s `master`—could be true, but would be totally irrelevant to *your* Git.

---

<sup>1</sup>A branch is, technically, any reference whose *full* name starts with `refs/heads/`.  A remote-tracking name is any reference whose full name starts with `refs/remotes/`.  Git normally strips off the `refs/heads/` and `refs/remotes/` parts for display, though sometimes—in `git branch -a` output, for instance—it only strips `refs/` from the remote-tracking names.  A few Git commands, such as `git for-each-ref`, display the full reference name by default; generally it's only the so-called *plumbing* commands that keep the whole name.

---

#### Conclusion

When dealing with Git, always remember:

- A repository holds *commits*.  Each commit holds files, so in the end, the repository also holds files, but it does it a commit at a time.  Each commit has a unique hash ID.
- There's almost always more than one repository.
- When connecting two repositories to each other, they share commits by hash ID.  The sending Git and receiving Git converse and exchange hash IDs, to see who has what and who needs what.  Then the sender sends *commits*—not files, but whole commits—to the receiver.  Now the sender and receiver have the same *commits*, by hash ID.
- If you're using `git push`, you're the sender, and they are the receiver.  At the end, your Git either politely asks their Git a question: *If you are willing, please set some of your branch and/or tag names to some particular commit hash IDs?* or it commands them, as in `git push --force`: *Set these branch and/or tag names to these hash IDs!*  The hash IDs come from *your* Git, and correspond to the commits that your Git has just shared if necessary (if they didn't have them already).

  They can refuse!  A polite request will be refused if they would *lose* some commits by setting a branch name, for instance.  A command is obeyed or refused depending on controls and permissions—the default is to always obey, but web hosting services always offer controls these days.

  If they obey the request or command, your Git will update your remote-tracking names.  (Your Git doesn't know about any *other* names they've updated or not-updated, so your Git only updates your remote-tracking names for branch names you had them set.)
- If you're using `git fetch`, your Git is the receiver.  In most cases, you get *all* their branch names, and your Git then updates *all* your remote-tracking names.  You can deliberately limit the names your Git asks their Git about, though.  For instance:

  ```
  git fetch origin master
  ```

  has your Git call up their Git and ask them only about their `master`.  You get any new commits they have that you don't, and then your Git only updates your own `origin/master`—you didn't pick any other branches to look at, so your Git doesn't.

  You can also set *single-branch mode* on any remote.  That's what `git remote add` does when used with `-t`.  In this mode, your `git fetch` *automatically* only asks about the one branch you listed.  This is rarely very useful: it's mostly to deal with huge, highly active repositories where you're only looking at, or contributing to, a small part (one branch) so you don't care about all the activity in most of the remote.  You can do this for small and less-active repositories, but unless you have a 9600 baud internet connection, it's not going to save you enough time to bother with.
- `git pull` just means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command*.  The `git fetch` is where all the remote-repository get-me-their-commits happens.  This also updated your `origin/master` or whatever.  The *second* Git command is useful *because* `git fetch` doesn't touch *your* branches.  Usually, after you've fetched *their* new `master` commits, you'd also like to update *your* `master`.

  One of several problems here, though, is *how* you want to update your `master`.  Do you want to update it with `git merge`, or do you want to update it with `git rebase`?  If you know, for certain, in advance, *which* command you want to use, you can run `git pull`: `git pull --rebase` will run `git rebase` and `git pull` without `--rebase` will run `git merge`, as the second command.  Then you'll be done, and one `git pull` is more convenient than a `git fetch` followed by a second Git command.

  But if you *don't* know for sure whether you want `git merge` or `git rebase` or perhaps something else entirely, then `git pull` is a trap.  What I like to do is run `git fetch`, then *inspect what I just got*, and only **then** decide what to do.  The `git pull` command makes you decide what you will do, before you can see what you got.  So I generally avoid it—but that's me, in my situation, which may differ from you in yours.

  (In very old versions of Git, back in the 1.5 and 1.6 days, `git pull` had a well deserved reputation for accidentally destroying your work, too.  I lost some work to `git pull` bugs myself.)

Comment: This was not the answer but your reply was very in depth and useful so I have upvoted. I will add the solution later today.