# How can I stop Git from sending me the message "Your branch is based on 'origin/branch_name', but the upstream is gone."

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm working on an engineering project with a colleague and we wanted to try out two different routes. I decided to use Git branches so we could split the code and I could try my own way of solving the problem, he could try his own and finally we could compare which worked better.
So I created two branches, let's say, "Francesco" and "Marco".
Unfortunately, I did a mistake: I committed a change I intended for my own branch on the master branch and pushed it to the remote before realising I had messed up. I didn't despair though and reverted the last commit using:

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD~
$ git checkout Francesco
```

So far so good. Now the situation looks something like this, with branch "Francesco" beyond master by one commit:

```
73ef6b6 (HEAD -> Francesco, origin/master, origin/HEAD) some commit message
ae09794 (master, Marco) Some other commit message
```

The problem I face now is that the origin/master is still one commit beyond the master on my local machine. I want to make the situation in the remote repository on GitHub look exactly like the situation on my local folder.
I try:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git push
```

As a response for my first command I get:

```
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

(Which of course is exactly the opposite of what i want to achieve).
An then from the second one I get:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Francesco-Ghizzo/Idrodinamica'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Git is suggesting me again to overwrite my local folder with the content of the remote repository by pulling it, which is the opposite of what I intend to do.
At this point, as a desperate move, I try:

```
$ git push -f
```

Everything now seems to work fine:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
$ git log --oneline
73ef6b6 (HEAD -> Francesco) some commit message
ae09794 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master, Marco) some other commit message
```

until I try to push committed changes on my own branch. I tried to set up my branch in the remote repository by typing:

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin Francesco
```

But then, whenever I try to commit a change, I get the message:

```
On branch Francesco
Your branch is based on 'origin/Francesco', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)
```

even if I have already typed

```
$ git branch --unset-upstream
```

many times. Did I mess up something when forcing the push? How can I stop git sending me this message every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no `remote branch` called 'Francesco' anymore.

If the branch doesn't exist in your repository, you can create it again (with the commits of your local branch) with the command:

```
git push --set-upstream origin Francesco
```

If that's not the case, (if the remote branch exists) you can tell your local branch to follow it with the command:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/Francesco
```

I think that this issue is related with [Why call git branch --unset-upstream to fixup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609781/why-call-git-branch-unset-upstream-to-fixup)

The answer given in the issue linked is pretty well explained and you will probably have all the elements of information to understand and fix your problem.