# How can I work with a local branch and a remote branch?

Tags: git, git-remote

I am working with a local repository and a repository on my server. The server branch should have the name "master" and the local branch I would like to name "local".

With `git branch -a` I listed all my branches:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

I guess that `* master` here is the local repository I am actually working at the moment.
What I do not understand is, what is `origin/HEAD ?` and why is it pointing to `origin/master`?

Is `origin/master` the same as `master`? I am confused.

So as a result I think I would need only this:

```
* local
remotes/origin/master
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess that `* master` here is the local repository I am actually working at the moment.

Yes, but that's not the whole story.

> What I do not understand is, what is `origin/HEAD`? and why is it pointing to `origin/master`?

As [knittl said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73728829/1256452), you can usually just ignore it.  What it is, is a *symbolic reference*.  What *that* is, well, we'll come back to that.

One of the keys to understanding Git is to [grok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok) the idea that "everything is local".  What that means is that—aside from some rare but important exceptions like when you run `git fetch` or `git push`—Git doesn't think about "other repositories" at all.  There is only *your* repository.  Everything is in *your repository!*  That's all that *exists*, so everything *has* to be there.

To make that work, we start with the *repository*.  At its heart, what a Git repository *is*, is a pair of databases.  One database holds commit objects and other supporting objects (commits themselves are truly tiny and need other stuff to make them useful).  The second database holds *names*, which we need because the keys used in the *first* database are so ugly.

Both databases are simple [key-value stores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database).  The objects database, holding commits and supporting objects, uses *hash IDs* as the keys.  Given the hash ID, Git can quickly retrieve the object; when the object is a commit object (containing the commit's metadata), Git can use that to retrieve a full snapshot of all files.  But the hash IDs—which Git *needs:* it can't retrieve the object without its hash ID—are too hard for human brains and fingers.  So the *names* database holds names—branch names, tag names, and many other kinds of names—and maps those names to the hash IDs that Git needs.

Once you understand this, and that `master` is short for the *name* `refs/heads/master` which is specifically a *branch* name because it starts with `refs/heads/`, you can see how Git takes the name `master`, puts the `refs/heads/` back on the front, finds the name in the *names* database, uses that to retrieve the correct *commit hash ID*, and uses that hash ID to retrieve the commit's content (metadata and snapshot).

That's *almost* the whole story.  The rest is much longer, but is really just the filling-in of details.

## The whole story

The *interesting* names—by which I mean, the names that aren't ones that Git uses internally, such as replacement names or bisection temporary names, or `refs/stash` for `git stash`, or whatever—fall into some major groups:

- *Branch* names are those that start with `refs/heads/`.
- *Tag* names are those that start with `refs/tags/`.
- *Remote-tracking* names<sup>1</sup> are those that start with `refs/remotes/`.

Almost all names start with `refs/`.  There are some funny ones, like `HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`, and the like that don't, but they tend to contain `HEAD` (in all uppercase like this).  Git calls the names *references*, and is not always consistent about whether the funny ones are references (sometimes they are "pseudo-refs").  *Most* refs contain one (1) raw hash ID.

Sometimes, *some* refs contain *the name of another ref*.  Git calls this a *symbolic reference* (or *symref* or similar for short).  The only one of these that "always works right" in general, in all versions of Git, is `HEAD`.  Long ago (back in the days of Git 1.7 perhaps) I made a test repository with a "branch" named `INDIR` containing the name of another branch.  Asking Git to delete INDIR resulted in Git deleting the other branch!  This is long since fixed, but it shows that symbolic refs are tricky.

When `HEAD` is a symref—which it usually is—it contains the *branch that you're on*.  In fact, that's precisely how Git knows which branch you're on: the special name `HEAD` contains the branch name.  So when you see:

```
* master
  next
```

in your `git branch` output for instance, this just means that `HEAD` contains the name `master`, so that you're on your `master` branch.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git calls them "remote-tracking branch names", but the word "branch" here is a bad idea in my opinion.  In some error messages and documentation, Git calls them "remote branch names", which is even worse (again in my opinion).  The phrase *remote-tracking name* isn't great either, but it's better than these two alternatives.

---

#### Branch names are slightly special

The ability to be "on" a branch name—using `git switch` or `git checkout` to select that branch name as the *current* branch name, which is then recorded in the special name `HEAD`—already makes a branch name slightly special.  You can't pull this same trick with a tag or remote-tracking name, for instance:

```
git switch v2.1.0
```

gives you an error, as does:

```
git switch origin/master
```

(assuming there is an `origin/master` name—if not, you get an error there too, but it's a different error):

```
fatal: a branch is expected, got tag 'v2.1.0'
```

or:

```
fatal: a branch is expected, got remote branch 'origin/master'
```

You can't be "on" a tag or a remote-tracking name.  That's because they are not *branch* names.  You can only be "on" a *branch* (name), or in "detached HEAD" mode, using `git switch --detach`.

Ignoring the case of detached-HEAD mode—which is not the way you normally want to work<sup>2</sup>—you are, then, always "on" some branch name, which means you need at least one branch name in your repository.  You can have as many branch names as you want, or as few.  Each one holds a hash ID—as every (non-symbolic) name does—so that *name* helps you, and Git, find *that particular commit*.

Note that you can have many names for one commit!  That's perfectly fine: if you want version 1.0 to be version 1.0.0 as well, just make two tag names for that commit.  You can do this with branch names too: given a commit hash ID `H` (where `H` stands in for the real hash ID), you can make two, or ten, or a million, branch names, all of which store hash ID `H`.

But let's get back to the really special property of a branch name.  The act of *checking out* a commit, whether by name or directly by hash ID, whether "on a branch" or in "detached HEAD" mode, *extracts* all the files *from* that commit, so that you can use them.  But if you change some files in your working tree and `git add` the updated files and run `git commit`, you get a *new commit*, with a new unique hash ID—and **if you're "on" some branch**, Git will *store that new hash ID in the branch name*.  That is, Git will read `HEAD`, and if it's a symbolic ref to some branch name, Git will *stuff the new commit hash ID* into the names database, under that branch name.

**So the special property of a branch name is that it contains the hash ID of the most recent commit that is "on" that branch.**  This is actually the *definition*.  It's not an accidental consequence of "new commit causes Git to update current branch name": the "new commit makes Git update" is, instead, a consequence of the definition of the special property.

You can, at any time, *force* any particular (existing) hash ID to go into any branch name.  When you do that, the commit hash ID you've forced into that branch name *is* the *last* commit that is on that branch.  You can, at any time, *create a new branch name* by selecting some commit hash ID and having Git create a new database entry using that ID, and when you do that, the commit you selected *is* the *last* commit that is on that branch.

There are usually some (or many) *earlier* commits *also* on that branch, but you don't specify them.  They're specified *in the commits*.  You pick the *last* commit and that *comes with* earlier commits.  **In the end, it's the commits that matter.  You just find the *most recent* one, quickly and easily, using a branch name.**  The branch names move and change, over time, so that you can find *particular* commits quickly and easily.

Hence, you want to answer, to yourself, this question:  Which commits do you want to find quickly and easily?  Those are ones for which you might consider creating branch names.

---

<sup>2</sup>The `git rebase` command works in detached-HEAD mode until the rebase is complete.  You may also want to use `git switch --detach` to look at, or use, a historical commit by its raw hash ID, without having to bother to invent a name for it.  If you make *new* commits in this mode, though, you'll eventually run into problems, so except for the special case of rebasing, you really don't want to work in this mode.

The fact that this mode exists is why Git doesn't actually *need* any branch names at all.  The fact that working in this mode will make you miserable is why you really *want* to have at least one branch name.

---

#### Sending commits with `git push`

Now, I noted above that Git normally thinks of itself as the king of all repositories because *this* repository—the one you're using right now—is the *only* repository.<sup>3</sup>  But sometimes, every now and then, we'd like to connect *this* repository to *some other repository*, using `git fetch` if we want to *get their new commits* from them, or `git push` if we want to send our new commits to them.

*Sending* our commits is somewhat straightforward.  *All Git repositories ultimately find, and identify, commits by hash ID*, so we just present the raw hash IDs of our *latest* commit(s) to the other Git software.  If they have those commits already, they will know, because hash IDs are *unique* but also *universal*.  If not, they will know, because hash IDs are unique: they either have something with that hash ID, in which case, they have *that commit*, or they don't, in which case they don't have *that commit*.  This unique-yet-universal property is the deep magic that propels the distributed part of Git as a DVCS.

So, we send them our new commits, which in general should *add on* to their existing commits.  Then we ask them to create a new branch name, or update some existing branch name, so that they can remember, in *their* repository, the *latest* commit.  That's what `git push` is all about: we send them commits, then we ask them to create or update some of their branch names.<sup>4</sup>  For convenience, Git lets us do this as:

```
git push <remote> <branch>
```

where the *`remote`* part is typically the string literal `origin`, which is the standard first (and often only) *remote*, which we haven't defined here, but which provides a URL by which our Git software can call up their Git software, whoever "they" may be, and ask them to stuff these commits into their repository and update their branch.

The *`branch`* argument here specifies both the *commit* (or commits) to send from our repository, starting (or ending?) with the *last* commit on our branch named *`branch`*, *and* the branch name we'd like their Git software to update.  This way if *we* have a branch named `feature/tall`, we can easily ask them to create or update a branch in *their* repository that is *also* named `feature/tall`.

**Note the key concept here: we have *our* branch names, and they have *their* branch names.**  We often—perhaps even almost all the time—want to use the *same name* in our repository that they're using in their repository, and vice versa.  We do this because:

- it makes sense to poor, easily-confused humans; and/or
- we're lazy and prefer this `git push origin feature/tall` syntax; and/or
- whatever other reason you like.

It's *possible* to use *different names* on each "side", so that we have the name `feature/tall` while they have the name `bob/loves/lisa` or something equally silly.  (The syntax for this is `git push origin feature/tall:bob/loves/lisa`.)  Because we can use Git without any branch names at all, we can even use a raw commit hash ID on our side.  But we *have to* use a *name* on their side: that's part of the defined Git protocol.  It does not have to be a *branch* name—it can be a tag name, or some other kind of name—but it has to be a name, and they have to *allow* it, all of which is up to them.

---

<sup>3</sup>This was originally reflected in the Git source code as a bunch of global variables holding the data for *the* (as in, one, single, the only) repository.  As Git evolved, the code improved to the point where there's now a data structure representing *a* repository, so that Git code could, in theory, work with more than one repository at a time—but there's still a global variable holding *the* repository.

Note that Git used to have the same issue with *the* working tree.  Adding more working trees, via `git worktree add`, which was new in Git 2.5, meant gathering all those global variables up into a data structure, and creating multiple instances of the work-tree structure.  There was more to it than just that, but that was a lot of the work.  As there were some nasty bugs that were not fixed until Git 2.15, it's clear that this change was tricky.

<sup>4</sup>We can ask them to create or update a tag name, or indeed, any kind of name at all, and we can ask them to delete some of their names.  A single `git push` can request to send as many, or as few, objects as we like, and it can send as many, or as few, create/update/delete requests for ref-names as we like.  But *most* of the time, we mostly use `git push` with one *branch* name.

---

#### Getting commits with `git fetch`

As with the sending process above, Git concedes (slightly) that other repositories exist, for the purpose of *getting* commits *from* them.  To do this we use `git fetch`.  Note that `git clone`, which copies an entire repository full of commits, also uses `git fetch` to get those commits: clone is just a wrapper that creates a new, empty repository, sets it up so that `git fetch` can run, runs `git fetch`, and then creates one branch and checks it out.

When we *do* run `git fetch`, our Git software can *see* all of their names: all their branch names, all their tag names, and even all of their other names.<sup>5</sup>  In the early days of Git—before "remotes" were invented—these names just got stashed in a file you could look at later if you wanted, but people very quickly realized that these names were immensely valuable.

This happens because humans are human.  We give names to branches because *we believe* that their most recent *commits* are valuable.  We *choose* the names to reflect something *about* this value, e.g., `feature/tall` as a name tells us that this is a new feature we're working on to make the repository grow taller.<sup>6</sup>

So, if some other repository—one that we call `origin`—has a *branch* named `master`, that indicates that they, whoever they are, think there's something important named `master`.  This might be important to us!  Or, it might not.

Our Git software will, as a default and matter of course, *create or update* a *remote-tracking name* in *our* repository.  This remote-tracking name will identify the *same commit* that their `master` identifies.  Every time we run `git fetch`,<sup>7</sup> our Git will check their `master` and update our remote-tracking name as appropriate.

Our Git software will build the name that our repository will use—the remote-tracking name—by starting with `refs/remotes/`, which is required for all remote-tracking names, then adding the name of the remote itself, which is almost always `origin` here.  Then our Git software adds one more slash, and then it copies the (shortened) branch name.  So if *they* have `refs/heads/master`—the branch named `master`—*we* get `refs/remotes/origin/master`.

To put it more simply, though less precisely, our Git software just takes each of their *branch* names and renames them by sticking `origin/` in front.  These become our remote-tracking names.  Our Git *repository* gets all of their commits, and all the ones *they think are important*—as indicated by having a branch name that selects that commit—get marked up in *our* repository using our remote-tracking names.

---

<sup>5</sup>Technically, we see only those names they permit us to see.  Git has some configuration items to hide various refs or namespaces.  Servers may use this for various purposes, for instance.  It's not meant as a real security mechanism, because `git fetch` can request objects by raw hash IDs directly, so even if someone can't see some *name*, they might be able to find a hash ID and get the object that way.  As a Git user, or even as a security officer, you should think of anything that's in *any* Git repository as being *fully exposed* to anyone who can see any part of that repository.  Access security in Git tends to be an all-or-nothing deal, and that's by Linus Torvald's design: if they can't load *any part* of the repository, they can't get anything, but if they *can* load any part of the repository, they can load *all* of the repository.

<sup>6</sup>Whatever *that* means.  I think it refers to how, if one just has enough will power, one can get taller, just as we use will power to gain or lose weight.

<sup>7</sup>You can run `git fetch` in a *limited mode*, where it's unable to update all remote-tracking names.  Or, you can run it in its more normal, unlimited mode: `git fetch origin` or even just `git fetch`.  In the *unlimited* mode, this will update all your remote-tracking names.  There are a bunch of exceptions here though—not just the limited mode—and older versions of Git—pre-1.8.4—are particularly bad about them.

Note that there's a thing I consider a sort of a bug here.  Suppose their Git repository has a branch named `xyzzy`, but only *briefly*.  If you run `git fetch origin` *while* they have `xyzzy`, your Git sees their `xyzzy` and creates your own `origin/xyzzy`.  That's all fine.  But then they *delete* their `xyzzy` and you run `git fetch` again.  This time they have no branch named `xyzzy`.  OK, so what?  Well, so: *your Git software fails to delete your `origin/xyzzy`.*  Your `origin/xyzzy` represents a branch name that *used to exist, but no longer exists*.

Is this bad?  No, not really, it's so very minor; but yes, it's awful—it's terrible!  It all depends on your point of view, and also on how often and how many of these "stale" remote-tracking names you accumulate.  If "their" repository creates 10000 of these a minute and you pick them *all* up, you have millions of them by the next day (1.44 million, to be precise).  They clutter things up.

You can instruct your Git software to *delete* these "stale" remote-tracking names using `git fetch --prune` or `git remote prune`, or you can configure `fetch.prune` to `true`.  I think this probably should be the default, myself (so I have it configured to `true`).

---

#### Back to your original question

> With `git branch -a` I listed all my branches:
>
> ```
> * master
>   remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
>   remotes/origin/master
> ```

What you have here is three names, but they're not all *branch* names.  The `git branch -a` command lists both *branch* names and *remote-tracking names*.

If you use `git branch` with no options, you get a listing of your branch names, with `refs/heads/` removed, so that you would just see `master`.

If you use `git branch -r` to view remote-tracking names, you get a listing of your remote-tracking names, with `refs/remotes/` removed, so that you would see `origin/HEAD` and `origin/master`.

For some reason—nobody seems to know why—when you use `git branch -a` to list both, the section that lists remote-tracking names removes only `refs/` instead of `refs/remotes`, so that you see the three you showed above.

The middle one of these three is a *symbolic reference*, which only really works right for `HEAD`.  When your Git software calls up their Git software with `git fetch`, they will show not only their regular refs, but also the `HEAD` pseudo-ref, and your Git can use that to figure out which branch they are "on".  The Git developers seem to have had a more detailed plan for this at one point, but for now, aside from `git clone` time, there seems to be little practical use for this information.  That's why you can just ignore it.<sup>8</sup>

The `origin/main` name is your own local name, but it *reflects that your Git software saw a branch named `main` in their Git's listing*.  Every time you run `git fetch` to `origin` (though see footnote 7) your Git will *update* this.

---

<sup>8</sup>The `git remote` command has some sub-commands designed to *manipulate* this.  There are some ways you could use this, but I never do: I find little value here, *and* I worry that at some point, the Git developers might resurrect whatever plan *they* had that would conflict with anything I wanted to do with it.  So I just ignore it myself.

What `git clone` does with this information is straightforward.  When you run `git clone url`, you're allowed to specify a *branch name* with the `-b` option.  If you do specify such a name, that's the name your Git will try to create and check out, after running `git fetch`.  If you *don't*, though—and most people mostly don't, it seems—your Git uses their `HEAD` to figure out which *name* they recommend.  Git calls that the *default branch* and hosting sites like GitHub typically let you set this (but Google do not let you set the default branch, which wasn't important until the Great Renaming from master to main, and now it's kind of a problem).

---

#### Summary

> Is `origin/master` the same as `master`? I am confused.

`origin/master` is a *remote-tracking name*, representing their (some other Git repository that you call `origin`) `master` branch name.  This name makes it easy for you to find a specific commit.

`master` is a *branch name*, making it easy for you to find a specific commit.

Right after `git clone`, *both* names represent *the same commit*.  Since branch names move when you move them, you can change yours; since their branch name will move when they move it, they can change theirs; if either of you change the hash ID stored in either name, they will stop representing the same name.

> ... the local branch I would like to name "local".

So create a branch named `local`, or rename the name `master` to `local`.

There's one caveat about renaming the existing `master`, as there's something about branch names I did not cover above.  Each branch name can have one (1) *upstream* set.  Or it can have no upstream at all.  The upstream setting of a branch name is supposed to gain you some convenience.  When and whether you find this convenient is up to you: some people don't bother at all.

The existing `master` will have its upstream set to `origin/master`.  If you create a new branch name `local`, you can choose whether it has any upstream setting, and if so, what that is.  If you rename the existing `master` it will retain its current upstream setting—but you can, if you like, then *change or remove* the upstream setting.

For more about upstreams, see [Why do I need to do `--set-upstream` all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6089294/1256452) and [Why call git branch --unset-upstream to fixup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21609781/1256452) (and other questions mentioning upstream).

Comment: This is comprehensive, but it really needs a TL/DR at the top.

Comment: @chepner: Well, yes, but the tl;dr is probably "see knittl's answer" 

Comment: terrific answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

`origin/HEAD` is the default branch of the remote repository with name `origin`. You can usually ignore it.

To rename your local branch, run `git branch -m local master`, `git checkout master && git branch -m local`, or `git checkout -f local master && git branch -d master`.

Answer (score 1):

Good evening!

You can look at .git directory and find there next path:
.git/refs/**remotes**/origin/HEAD

You also can cat it:

```
cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
```

That means that remote HEAD refers to a remote master

*jfyi*
You can also see where the local HEAD refers to

```
cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
```

Comment: There may not be such a file. Git will sometimes "pack" refs. A future version of Git will have a "ref table" database instead of individual files.